# Is it normal for BibTeX to replace similar author names with "------"?

Tags: bibtex, rules, ieee-style

In my `.bib` file, I have two entries with exactly the same author names:

```
@article{Seshadrinathan2010A-Subjective-St,
    Author = {K. Seshadrinathan and R. Soundararajan and A. C. Bovik and L. K. Cormack},
....

@article{Seshadrinathan2009Study-of-Subjec,
    Author = {K. Seshadrinathan and R. Soundararajan and A. C. Bovik and L. K. Cormack},
....
```

When cited after each other, and typeset with the `IEEEtran` bibliography style, the `.bbl` file reads:

```
\bibitem{Seshadrinathan2010A-Subjective-St}
K.~Seshadrinathan, R.~Soundararajan, A.~C. Bovik, and L.~K. Cormack, ``A
  subjective study to evaluate video quality assessment algorithms,''
  \emph{SPIE Proceedings Human Vision and Electronic Imaging}, 2010.

\bibitem{Seshadrinathan2009Study-of-Subjec}
------, ``Study of subjective and objective quality assessment of video,''
  \emph{IEEE Transactions on Image Processing}, 2009.
```

As you can see, the author names have been replaced with `------`. It looks like this in the final PDF:

[image]

Is this normal behavior?

Comment: It depends on the bibliography style. This bahavior is normal for style `IEEEtrans`.

Comment: *Most* other bibliography styles don't have this behavior.

Comment: As suggested in [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49140/get-full-name-twice-in-bibliography)
\usepackage[style=ieee,dashed=false]{biblatex}

Comment: @Javad where should I put the function ?

Comment: @Javad Just put `\usepackage[style=ieee,dashed=false]{biblatex}` in your document, at the top in the preamble where you load the other packages.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

The behavior mentioned is the default using `IEEEtran.bst` style. To change it, you can define a `IEEEtranBSTCTL` entry in your bib database and change the default value for `CTLdash_repeated_names`. So, in this case, your entry should look like this:

```
@IEEEtranBSTCTL{IEEEexample:BSTcontrol,
  CTLdash_repeated_names = "no"
}
```

Then in the body of your `.tex` file you have to activate the change by using

```
\bstctlcite{IEEEexample:BSTcontrol}
```

#### Example (thanks to Marco):

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@IEEEtranBSTCTL{IEEEexample:BSTcontrol,
CTLdash_repeated_names= "no",
}

@article{Seshadrinathan2010A-Subjective-St,
    Author = {K. Seshadrinathan and R. Soundararajan and A. C. Bovik and L. K. Cormack},
    title={foo},
    year={2011},
    journal={bla}
}

@article{Seshadrinathan2009Study-of-Subjec,
    Author = {K. Seshadrinathan and R. Soundararajan and A. C. Bovik and L. K. Cormack},
    title={bar},
    year={2010},
    journal={bla}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{IEEEtran}
%\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}% only needed if a class different from IEEEtran is used.


\begin{document}
\bstctlcite{IEEEexample:BSTcontrol}
\cite{Seshadrinathan2010A-Subjective-St}

\cite{Seshadrinathan2009Study-of-Subjec}


\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: +1, but I think that both your and my method may have merit.

Comment: @lockstep: I don't think so. To define a small `bibsetup.bib` (maybe with `filecontents`) is much easier and more comfortable for the user as the manipulation of the bst-file.

Comment: Okay, so I put this right at the top of my `.bib` file, trashed all auxiliary files, ran `pdflatex`, `bibtex`, `pdflatex` twice, and it's still there? I'm not particularly worried about it if it's normal, but it would be nice to know how to get rid of it.

Comment: @Marco: See slhck's comment for an example how "much easier and more comfortable  for the user" it is.

Comment: @slhck: please post a minimal example showing the problem. I did some tests before posting my answer and everything worked as expected.

Comment: @lockstep: I didn't say your method had no merit; I only said there was no need to make a copy of the file and edit it.

Comment: @Gonzalo: I know, and I think your answer deserves more upvotes than my one. However, I don't think my answer deserves a downvote.

Comment: @lockstep: I don't think either that it deserves a down-vote. (And it wasn't me who down-voted it).

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Please feel free to use the example ;-)

Comment: @lockstep: The same problem you mentioned: The documentation of the bst-file is the key ;-) [IEEEtran_bst_HOWTO.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/bibtex/IEEEtran_bst_HOWTO.pdf)

Comment: @Marco: So, you need to define a file `bibsetup.bib` *and* to load the `ieeetrantools` package *and* to issue `\bstctlcite{IEEEexample:BSTcontrol}`. But modifying a copy of `IEEEtran.bst` is without merit?

Comment: @lockstep: `bibsetup.bib` was an example (please see mwe). The package is part of the style ;-)

Comment: @Marco: thanks for the example. I added the image of the output, and a comment on `\bstctlcite{IEEEexample:BSTcontrol}`.

Comment: @slhck: see the updated answer.

Comment: @Marco: I slightly modified the example. I used `IEEEtran.cls` and commented out the package `IEEEtrantools` with a note to use it with other classes. I hope it's OK with you.

Comment: @Marco: I tested your MWE. Perhaps you should mention (as it won't be obvious for unversed users) that `\bstctlcite` must be used in the document body, not in the preamble.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: I create the example to test you answer ;-) Maybe it is helpfully ;-)

Comment: @lockstep: Sure but it is the example of Gonzalo ;-)

Comment: Thanks, I'll use that as a starting point! The document I have is very complicated, so it might be there are some issues with mine.

Comment: I was using the IEEEtranBST.zip from the paperplaza website. I had the same problem and I only opened the IEEEtran.bst and changed the  #1 to #0 for the default.is.dash.repeated.names and it solved the problem.

Comment: I tried the above steps and it work only for two references with the same author. However, I have 4 references with same author. Only two are showing the author's name while the 3rd and 4th are showing "------". Any work suggestions!!

Comment: @EngS Please feel free to open a new question providing there a MWE showing the mentioned behaviour.

Comment: @EngS, I have the same problem.

Answer (score 44):

To remove the dash, copy the file `IEEEtran.bst`, located in `/bibtex/bst/IEEEtran` of your TeX distribution, to your working directory and rename it to `myIEEEtran.bst`. In the renamed copy, replace

```
FUNCTION {default.is.dash.repeated.names} { #1 }
```

with

```
FUNCTION {default.is.dash.repeated.names} { #0 }
```

and compile your `.tex` document using `\bibliographystyle{myieeetran}`.

EDIT: To the person who downvoted: The original (commented) code in `IEEEtran.bst` reads

```
% #0 turns off the "dashification" of repeated (i.e., identical to those
% of the previous entry) names. IEEE normally does this.
% #1 enables
FUNCTION {default.is.dash.repeated.names} { #1 }
```

so I think the style designer(s) viewed changing `#1` to `#0` as a valid method of customization.

Comment: In this case there's really no need to edit a copy of the `.bst` file; see my answer.

Comment: I was using the IEEEtranBST.zip from the paperplaza website. I had the same problem and I only opened the IEEEtran.bst and changed the #1 to #0 for the default.is.dash.repeated.names and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 30):

It depends on the bibliography style. This behavior is normal for style `IEEEtrans`.

Some bibliography styles are illustrated on the page [BibTeX Style Examples](http://www.cs.stir.ac.uk/%7Ekjt/software/latex/showbst.html).

At this point I recommend the package [`biblatex`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib) where you can set this behavior via the `dashed` option. As answered [in this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49140/get-full-name-twice-in-bibliography).

The package itself doesn't provide an `IEEEtran` style but there is a [contrib](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/exptl/biblatex-contrib): [biblatex-ieee](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-ieee).

Comment: About your recommendation to use `biblatex`: is there a ready-made "style file" for biblatex that reproduces the look-and-feel of the IEEEtran .bst specification?

Comment: @Mico: I edited my post.

Comment: Wow, that's very useful information. Thanks.

Comment: I was using the IEEEtranBST.zip from the paperplaza website. I had the same problem and I only opened the IEEEtran.bst and changed the #1 to #0 for the default.is.dash.repeated.names and it solved the problem.

Comment: see also http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/131664/3888 for a workaround which allows disabling the dashes

Comment: @plainerman Thank you very much for mentioning the dashed option. Thats exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 16):

All of these solutions didn't work for me so I found a simple solution: just add  `\vspace{0mm}` to some part of the name of the author and it's OK.

Comment: Hmmm, you must be doing something different then.

Comment: This worked smoothly for me.

Answer (score 6):

Repeating @MarcoDaniel,  "It depends on the bibliography style. This bahavior is normal for style `IEEEtrans.`"

If you are writing a paper which asks for `IEEEtrans` (especially if this is to be published with IEEE), I would seriously consider simply using the default behavior as the result for your paper.  This is not a "fluke" that needs to be programed around, this is **exactly** how the style is programed and designed to perform.

You should always write your paper and choose your citation style based upon the style guide which has authority over your writing (teacher's choice, university style guide, corporate style guide, Chicago, APA, MLA, AP, &c.) and not your personal preferences.

Answer (score 2):

For me, the easiest way is to add {} between the author name in the bibtex file!

For example:
author = {{A. R. James and M. E. Xever}},

No need to do anything else, no packages, no editing original files, nothing :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use double curly brackets to override the IEEEtrans style.

**Example**

```
 @article{Seshadrinathan2010A-Subjective-St,
    Author = {K. Seshadrinathan and R. Soundararajan and A. C. Bovik and L. K. Cormack},

@article{Seshadrinathan2009Study-of-Subjec,
    Author = {{K. Seshadrinathan and R. Soundararajan and A. C. Bovik and L. K. Cormack}},
....
```

Then whatever you write within {{ }} will appear as you dictated.

Comment: This looks like another answer that was recently posted here (and subsequently deleted). It's a terrible workaround, because this “freezes” a certain style, making it impossible to use a different style based on the same BibTeX bibliography (e.g., one that uses *”et al.“* instead of all authors, or one that sorts last names before first names). Also, sorting of references (if alphabetical) in general would be screwed up.