# Get full name twice in Bibliography

Tags: biblatex

I use `biblatex` with `style=authoryear` and when there are two references of the same author in the bibliography there is just a dash. How can I get the full name in the second entry too?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Set the `dashed` option to false:

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear,dashed=false]{biblatex}
```

Comment: Just a comment: Google Scholar will not recognize dashed author names. So if one wants Google Scholar to index the references, make sure to always use the `dashed=false` option!