# suppressing dashes in bibliography

Tags: biblatex, chicago-style

I am using the `biblatex` `chicago` package. It's producing dashes for a repeating  author in the bibliography.

I tried different solution like, for example, including

```
\makeatletter
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \global\undef\bbx@lasthash%
  \clearfield{extrayear}}
\makeatother
```

but that does not work. How can I avoid dashes?

Comment: Have you tried the ''dashed=false'' package option, as suggested in this [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49140/get-full-name-twice-in-bibliography/49142#49142).

Comment: @Adam yes that option does not work in biblatex-chicago package

Answer (score 6):

Overwrite the macro with an empty box:

```
\renewcommand*\bibnamedash{\makebox[\leftmargin]{}}
```

or if you want to repeat the author name:

```
\usepackage[dashed=false,...]{biblatex}
```

And if it does not work than your bibstyle dowsn't support it. The style `authoryear` does it. For `biblatex-chicago` try:

```
...
\usepackage{biblatex-chicago}
\renewbibmacro*{author}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseauthor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{author}}
  }
    {\printnames{author}%
        \iffieldundef{authortype}
          {\setunit{\addspace}}
          {\setunit{\addcomma\space}}%
     \iffieldundef{authortype}
       {}
       {\usebibmacro{authorstrg}%
        \setunit{\addspace}}}%
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash
     \usebibmacro{labeltitle}%
     \setunit*{\addspace}}%
  \usebibmacro{date}}
 ...
```

which worked for me.

Comment: i want to print author name again for the repeated reference

Comment: than simply use `\usepackage[dashed=false,...]{biblatex}`

Comment: the problem is i m using biblatex-chicago which does not accept this.

Comment: see my edited answer

Comment: this code is generating year twice. if i remove data from last line then year is generated by the end of paper title. i want this by the end of author name

Comment: that is not possible with my code. Give a _complete_ example!

Answer (score 3):

If you just need to supress dashes try only

```
\makeatletter
\AtEveryBibitem{
  \global\undef\bbx@lasthash}
\makeatother
```

The part `\clearfield{extrayear}` is irrelevant to your problem. It should be removed.