# How to validate (check) a biblatex .bib file?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

How can I validate the correctness a `biblatex` .bib file?

Where validate means checking for:

- Duplicate keys
- Missing mandatory fields

What tools do you use?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

To validate my `.bib` files, I put together a Python script called [Biblatex Checker](https://github.com/pezmc/biblatex-check).

It checks for missing fields, provides suggestions for common mistakes when using `biblatex` and identifies duplicate IDs.

It's based on [BibTeX Check](https://code.google.com/p/bibtex-check/) by Fabian Beck, which can be used for BibTeX files.

Comment: I use `biber --tool -V bib.bib`. It doesn't complain about missing fields but I didn't try yet to find out how to change it (or in case in can't do it yet to make a feature request).

Comment: Actually, `-V` in tool mode didn't do anything in 1.8. It does in 1.9 dev version. For example it will report on mandatory fields missing from the default data model (in the tool mode config file). You can add any datamodel constraint you want to the data model (either by biblatex macros or via the biber config file for tool mode). The `blx-dm.def` file that comes with biblatex contains the default data model and its mandatory field constraints.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I think `biber --tool -V my.bib` should be a separate answer and, IMHO, the recommended way. I definitely would vote for it.

Answer (score 16):

I use [jabref](http://www.jabref.org/). Install jabref, set it to `biblatex` mode. To do this go to `Options` → `Preferences`. In the window that opens, select`Advanced` and check `BibLaTeX mode` as shown below.

[image]

Then open your `.bib` file using jabref. Select the entries to be cleaned up. Under `Tools` menu, select `cleanup entries`. This window opens:

[image]

Now you know what to do :)

For duplicate keys, simply go to `Tools` → `Autogenerate BibTeX keys`. It will rewrite the duplicate key with some other name.

Comment: So easy it was!  So, one needs to maintain different versions of references? one for BibTeX and another one for BibLaTeX?

Comment: @NikosAlexandris: For those who want perfection, it is the way. But for general needs bibtex is enough. The bibtex file serves for biblatex too if one is willing to live with some warnings etc.

Comment: I have an error now using BibLaTeX and XeLaTeX which was not there when using BibTeX and PDFLaTeX. Need to understand what is wrong and correct it. Two of my citations are printed with some long dash instead of the corresponsing author's name.

Comment: @NikosAlexandris Some where you are using `abbrv` style.

Comment: The .log has the following entry: `\c@abbrvpenalty=\count217`. I'll try to find the "error".

Comment: Actually, the solution to my "problem" is http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49142/8272

Answer (score 14):

If you are only given the `.bib` file, try

```
biber --tool --validate-datamodel <filename>.bib
```

If your TeX document uses custom data types, try

```
biber --validate-datamodel <filename>.bcf
```

This should check all data sources.

Comment: Note that the exact data model is style dependent, so usually the most complete and relevant report that you can get is the one issued by `biber --validate-datamodel <texfilebasename>` where `<texfilebasename>` is the basename of the `.tex` document you are writing at the moment.

Comment: I was assuming that one is given just a `.bib` file. Users of custom data models probably already know that `biber` can replace 3rd party tools.

Comment: Mhhh, I'm not so sure if people would realise that. Anyhow, at least for me `biber --tool` did not catch the four obvious errors in `@article{sugfridsson,
  editor   = {Sigfridsson, Emma and Ryde, Ulf},
  title    = {Title},
  blournal = {Journal},
}` that `--validate-datamodel` reported. So at least for the mandatory field validation `--tool` mode alone is not enough. I guess what I'm saying is that your answer would be better if you suggested `biber --validate-datamodel --tool <filename>.bib`

Answer (score 11):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Run `latex` and `bibtex` and then look into the *logfile*  of the `bibtex` run (`<filename>.blg`). It has all warnings.

Comment: I get no warnings for duplicate entries...

Answer (score 5):

https://biblatex-linter.herokuapp.com/ provides an online Bibtex linter.

It's an Heroku app (Python/Django). It's open source and MIT licensed. https://github.com/Pezmc/BibLaTeX-Linter.

It's based on https://github.com/Pezmc/BibLaTeX-Check

Answer (score 5):

[BibTex Tidy](https://flamingtempura.github.io/bibtex-tidy/) is an open source online tool, I've used it, and personally I found it to be very reliable. It supports formatting and clean up, but also checks duplicate entries, including not just the key but also titles.

The tool's self-description is:

> This tool tidies bibtex files by fixing inconsistent whitespace,
> removing duplicates, removing unwanted fields, and sorting entries.

Answer (score 2):

### [bibtool](https://ctan.org/pkg/bibtool) v2.68 (April 2020)

`bibtool` ([github](https://github.com/ge-ne/bibtool)) v2.68 has improved its double check (aka check for duplicates):

- The behaviour of the resource `check.double` has been
  generalized. The requirement of double entries to be adjacent
  has been dropped. This has the impact that the processing is
  slightly slower.

and added a new check `unique.field`:

- New resource file `unique.field` introduced. With this
  resource it is possible to specify additional unique constraints
  for fields. If different records have the same value for one of
  those fields, then a warning is issued.

Ensure you have v2.68 or newer (Homebrew for macOS already provides this version when this answer was written, ie. `$ brew upgrade bib-tool` gives you the new version)

```
❯ bibtool -V
BibTool Vers. 2.68 (C) 1996-2019 Gerd Neugebauer
```

#### Report duplicate keys

Following command reports records which share the same `$key`

```
❯ bibtool -- 'unique.field {$key}' -o '' unique_field_test.bib
```

For example, you could also check for duplicate dois.

```
❯ bibtool -- 'unique.field {doi}' -o '' unique_field_test.bib
```

#### Report about missing fields

I am not sure if this is already possible with `bibtool`.

Answer (score 0):

On top of the tools that have already been suggested, you can try my [`bibcop`](https://ctan.org/pkg/bibcop) package. You just `\usepackage` it in the document and any errors found in the `.bib` file will be reported as LaTeX warnings right in the TeX log:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bibcop}
\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{main}
\end{document}
```

Bibcop checks the formatting of the author, title, year, month, pages, and so on. If is written in Perl and you are welcome to [submit your suggestions](https://github.com/yegor256/bibcop) if you want it to be even stricter (it is pretty strict already!).

BTW, you can also use it as a command line tool to auto-fix your `.bib` file:

```
$ tlmgr install bibcop
$ bibcop --fix my.bib > fixed.bib
```

Comment: The package is indeed very strict with rules that seem pretty random and not based on anything other than personal choices. Some of them would also break some styles, e.g. capitalisation of titles/booktitles. Would be best to provide some reasoning behind the rules and/or warn that these are just the package author's preferences.

Comment: This is how most style checkers work (for other languages, like Java, C++, Python, etc.) -- their rules represent personal preferences of their authors. There is no absolute truth in style checking. Almost everything is a matter of taste. However, I agree, the documentation needs better explanation of the reasons behind each rule. I will try to extend it. BTW, the capitalization rule you mentioned is coming from [APA](https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/capitalization/title-case) (the documentation explicitly mentions this).

Comment: The APA capitalisation is indeed part of their style. encasing the whole field in double `{{}}` on the other hand means that a different style (thinking of my former institution which explicitly wants titles with only the first character capitalised (except acronyms)) would not be able to apply the correct (for them) capitalisation. A tool to check the validity of a file should not ask to counteract a style.

Comment: I will add a new package option `nocaps`, which will disable this particular checker. Also, `nobrackets` to disable the checker for double brackets.