# Automatically set proceedings/journal for bibliography (bibtex, mendeley)

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, mendeley

I think this is a really common issue but I'm having a hard time dealing with this.
I have a quite big collection of references which I collected using Mendeley.

Mendeley has a service to update reference with missing fields i.e. finding the right conference proceeding or journal where the publication is from.
While this is incredibly useful, it might fail sometime, so I still have a large number of publications without Journal/Proceedings values. I'm also using JabRef which has useful tools to generate citation keys, and suggest cleanup etc.

Is there a tool that, provided authors+title+year can update the metadata?
Google Scholar isn't accurate at all: lot of publications are said to be published by "arXiv" which isn't what I'm looking for (well, they are on arXiv but published in a conference right).

Thanks.

Comment: Did you check this already: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173621/how-to-validate-check-a-biblatex-bib-file ?