Avoid hours of debugging to fix formatting error into bibliography file
often I found that critical and not easy to debug problems, often not spotted as error during compiling, are due to malformed bibliography file, like missing comma, esotic character, etc.
I'm using latex and biblatex package with biber backend.
There is an automatic way to check validity of bibliography files?
Best Regards

Very related (although I'm not sure which issues you want to check for exactly and if the suggested solutions cover those): https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173621/how-to-validate-check-a-biblatex-bib-file

biber in tool mode? But if they are actual errors causing issues, the .blg and/or terminal output from the biber run should identify them?

if you check the bibtex syntax you may still get errors from bad latex in the bib file, so it's not clear what checks you would want other than just a minimal document with \cite{*} to include the whole file, tex errors will be in the .log and biber errors in the .blg  it is not clear why you say that errors in bibliographies are harder to spot, all errors are reported in the log files.

Thanks. It seems a little bit a duplicate of question linked by Marijn

I copy from cite link of google scholar so sometimes "unsupported character" are present in bibliography file, or just a comma separating fields is deleted by mistake: would be usefull to get errors showed by biber in tool mode when compiling latex.

"Unsupported character" errors can't easily be caught by Biber's tool mode since the list of supported characters depends on the engine you use and the document preamble. Missing commas will cause error messages in all Biber runs that usually have pretty accurate line numbers (remember that missing commas cause errors only a couple of lines later, so always check a couple lines above as well).

generally, I find biber's actual errors pretty clear - at least in comparison with some of those latex/tex produces. warnings are often not very clear, but those are obviously not critical for compilation. in general, I'd try to address the cause of introducing the problems into the files in the first place. is there an alternative source for your discipline which produces more reliable entries? or, if the errors are systematic, write a script to process them before adding. you should, in any case, always check entries because they often include errors.

About cfr's last point: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/386053/35864. You can probably avoid most outright syntax errors like missing commas after fields if you use a dedicated software for .bib files like JabRef, Bibdesk, ... (or reference managers like Zotero, Mendeley, Citavi ..., though especially the last two can be a bit stubborn as to how they export .bib files, from what I read Zotero is pretty customisable).

I'm using vim and vimtex plugin with latexmk (biber line: $biber = "biber --input-encoding=UTF-8 --output-encoding=UTF-8 --output-safechars --isbn-normalise %O %S";) and when compiling get no warning (even in log file) from biber syntax error, while when running biber in tool mode I get error. Maybe I have to look at that %O %S to add error log...
