# Don't sum up books in bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I'm using biblatex with biber backend and verbose-icomp preset. When citing in the text, I need the ibid-features, but mustn't use the compact features in the bibliography at the end.

Can I somehow remove this and let biblatex simply repeat itself for more books with the same author? This is especially a problem with internet sources, where no author is given. I have to use "k.A.", which is german short-form for "no author".

Here's what I've got:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[includefoot, footskip=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[style=verbose-ibid,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[autostyle=true,german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\bibliography{literature}
\begin{document}

Text-Sample1.\autocite{History:PGW} Text-Sample2.\autocite{AF:PGW} Text-Sample3.\autocite{Balt:Refugees}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

(I included all packages, because maybe something else is causing it and I'm just stupid and didn't noticed)

And the .bib-file:

```
@MISC{AF:PGW,
  AUTHOR       = {{k.A.}},
  TITLE        = "Activity 18. The Incubator Baby Incident. Reading18H-J",
  NOTE         = "<\url{http://www.globaled.org/curriculum/cm18h.html}> (abgerufen 29.10.2014)"
}

@MISC{MedienGleichschritt,
  AUTHOR       = {{k.A.}},
  TITLE        = "Der Zweite Golfkrieg. Medien im Gleichschritt",
  NOTE         = "<\url{http://medien04.uni-trier.de/buwiki/index.php/Der_Zweite_Golfkrieg:_Medien_im_Gleichschritt}> (abgerufen 31.10.2014)"
}

@MISC{Generation:ShieldStorm,
  AUTHOR       = {{k.A.}},
  TITLE        = "Desert Shield und Desert Storm",
  NOTE         = "<\url{http://www.generationenprojekt.de/1991/Golfkrieg.html}> (abgerufen 30.10.2014)"
}

@MISC{FAZ:HintergrundFlug,
  AUTHOR       = {{k.A.}},
  TITLE        = "Hintergrund. Flugverbotszonen",
  NOTE         = "<\url{http://www.faz.net/aktuell/politik/irak-hintergrund-flugverbotszonen-114559.html}> (abgerufen 30.10.2014)"
}

@MISC{Balt:Refugees,
  AUTHOR       = {{k.A.}},
  TITLE        = "Straggling refugees report electricity, water virtually gone in Iraq, Kuwait",
  NOTE         = "<\url{http://articles.baltimoresun.com/1991-02-18/news/1991049028_1_kuwait-baghdad-refugees}> (abgerufen 29.10.2014)"
}
```

So, with my code, it looks like this:

[image: How it's wrong]

What I need is that it's not summed up, so "k.A." isn't written out one time, and the rest is ordered with these bulletpoints.

So that it looks like this:

```
k.A.: Activity 18. The Incubator Baby Incident. Reading18H-J. <http://www.globaled.org/curriculum/cm18h.html> (abgerufen 29.10.2014).

k.A.: Der Zweite Golfkrieg. Medien im Gleichschritt. <http://medien04.uni-trier.de/buwiki/index.php/Der_Zweite_Golfkrieg:_Medien_im_Gleichschritt (abgerufen 31.10.2014).

k.A.: Desert Shield und Desert Storm. <http://www.generationenprojekt.de/1991/Golfkrieg.html> (abgerufen 30.10.2014).

k.A.: Hintergrund. Flugverbotszonen. <http://www.faz.net/aktuell/politik/irak-hintergrund-flugverbotszonen-114559.html> (abgerufen 30.10.2014).

k.A.: Straggling refugees report electricity, water virtually gone in Iraq, Kuwait. <http://articles.baltimoresun.com/1991-02-18/news/1991049028_1_kuwait-baghdad-refugees> (abgerufen 29.10.2014).
```

Comment: May you add some typical citations in the example document body?

Comment: If you use `biblatex`, the command `\printbibliography` does not take a mandatory argument (so use `\printbibliography` instead of `\printbibliography{literature}`), also `\bibliography{file}` is deprecated in favour of `\addbibresource{file.bib}` (note the file extension). Finally, your `.bib` file does not look really `biblatex`-y to me, `biblatex` provides the `url` and `urldate` field, so you don't have to abuse `note`. Also, I'm not quite sure what it is you want to see in your document, can you be a bit more precise?

Comment: I will add some citations in a few moments.

I'm using `\printbibliography`, I honestly have no idea why I wrote it with an argument.
For the .bib-file, I have to admin that I abused the note-field because I had to much trouble changing it to the right order with the right citation rules. Also my deadline is the day after tomorrow, therefore I disobeyed all rules of "clean, nice code" just to get it finished. 
What I want to have is that in the bibliography books with the same author are not summed up with bulletpoints, bur written out. I'll add a picture to make it clear.

Comment: Is it just `dashed=false` that you're looking for? (See for example [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13076/35864) and as a possible duplicate: [Get full name twice in Bibliography](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49140/35864)).

Comment: ....exactly. That worked like a charm. Now I'm really concerned about my reading abilities, because that is mentioned quite often, if I go through the instructions again now. I think I was just too stressed to see the easy things.

Anyway, thank you very much for the fast and helpful answer.

Comment: Good to hear that it does what it's supposed to do now. I voted to close this question as a duplicate of the one a linked to above.

Comment: `\bibliography{}` may officially be deprecated but it is much more convenient and works absolutely fine. (I still use this despite updating other aspects of my code because it is just a lot tidier and simpler.) Note that you can also specify separate styles for the bibliography and citations if you need to. (Obviously there are combinations which don't make sense. But you could specify e.g. compact author-year for one and regular author-year for the other.) `style=` is a convenience key which sets both at the same time.