# Having problems with sorting citation inline with biblatex and biber

Tags: biblatex

I am working on my thesis and having some problem with citations.
I am using biber and natbib.

The thing is when I cite in line with `\citep{ }` and want to cite several author like: 
`\citep{B-Athor, A-Author, Y-Author}` it does not sort the authors in alphabetically manner, it gives me the sequence in which I put it in the `\citep{ }` (B-Athor, A-Author, Y-Author) and not (A-Author, B-Athor, Y-Author).

At the end in the bibliography everything is sorted alphabtically

A second thing is that if I habe several papers from the same author but different years it gives me (A-Author 1200, A-Author 1300) I want: (A-Author 1200, 1300).

[image]

Than in the bibliography it gives me:

[image]

and not (I want it this way):

```
 A-Author 1200, Informaation about paper
 A-Author 1300, Informaation about paper
```

Hope someone can help

This here should compile and produce the problems that I have, using biber:

```
 \documentclass[11pt,a4paper,headsepline]{scrartcl}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
 \usepackage{kpfonts}
 \usepackage{libertine}
 \usepackage{siunitx}
 \usepackage[natbib=true,
        maxbibnames=99,
        maxcitenames=1,
        url=true,
        isbn=false,
        style=authoryear,
        uniquename=init,
        uniquelist=false, 
        firstinits=true,            
        sorting=anyt, 
        backend=biber]{biblatex}
     \renewbibmacro*{in:}{}   % in entfernen
   \renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\textsc{#1}}

 \DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{#1}
 \DeclareFieldFormat[incollection]{booktitle}{#1}
 \DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{#1\isdot}       
 \DeclareFieldFormat[inbook]{title}{#1\isdot}
 \DeclareFieldFormat[incollection]{title}{#1\isdot}
 \DeclareFieldFormat[book]{title}{#1}
  \renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{{\space\&\space}}
  \addbibresource{Biblio.bib}

 \begin{document}
 \section{test}
 \citep{ bender:1975, bender:1968, bender:1974}\\
 \citet{ bender:1975, bender:1968, bender:1974}

   \printbibliography

 \end{document}
```

using he .bib file:

```
@Book{bender:1975,
  Title                    = {Geology of the Arabian Peninsula - Jordan},
  Author                   = {F. Bender},
  Publisher                = {Geological Survey (U.S.)},
  Year                     = {1975} }

@Book{bender:1974,
  Title                    = {Geology of Jordan},
  Author                   = {F. Bender},
  Publisher                = {Gebrueder Borntraeger},
  Year                     = {1974} }

@InCollection{bender:1968,
  Title                    = {Geologie von Jordanien.},
  Author                   = {F. Bender},
  Booktitle                = {Beitraege zur Regionalen Geologie der Erde.},
  Year                     = {1968} }
```

Comment: Please update you MWE to something that actually compiles. Might also be a good idea to provide a sample `.bib` and add the `\cite` command. Making everything as easy as possible to those who might help, greatly increases your changes of getting help (or at least speed up the answers)

Comment: I changed it, so it should work

Comment: You want the option [`dashed=false`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49140/35864) and probably the style [`style=authoryear-comp`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples/52-style-authoryear-comp.pdf).

Answer (score 3):

You want the option [`dashed=false`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49140/35864) and the style [`authoryear-comp`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples/52-style-authoryear-comp.pdf).

Your MWE then becomes

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,headsepline]{scrartcl}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
 \usepackage{kpfonts}
 \usepackage{libertine}
 \usepackage{filecontents}
 \usepackage{siunitx}
 \usepackage[natbib=true,
        maxbibnames=99,
        maxcitenames=1,
        url=true,
        isbn=false,
        style=authoryear-comp,
        dashed=false,
        uniquename=init,
        uniquelist=false, 
        firstinits=true,            
        sorting=anyt, 
        backend=biber]{biblatex}


\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{bender:1975,
  Title                    = {Geology of the Arabian Peninsula - Jordan},
  Author                   = {F. Bender},
  Publisher                = {Geological Survey (U.S.)},
  Year                     = {1975} }

@Book{bender:1974,
  Title                    = {Geology of Jordan},
  Author                   = {F. Bender},
  Publisher                = {Gebrueder Borntraeger},
  Year                     = {1974} }

@InCollection{bender:1968,
  Title                    = {Geologie von Jordanien.},
  Author                   = {F. Bender},
  Booktitle                = {Beitraege zur Regionalen Geologie der Erde.},
  Year                     = {1968} }
\end{filecontents*}



     \renewbibmacro*{in:}{}   % in entfernen
   \renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\textsc{#1}}

 \DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{#1}
 \DeclareFieldFormat[incollection]{booktitle}{#1}
 \DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{#1\isdot}       
 \DeclareFieldFormat[inbook]{title}{#1\isdot}
 \DeclareFieldFormat[incollection]{title}{#1\isdot}
 \DeclareFieldFormat[book]{title}{#1}
  \renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{{\space\&\space}}
  \addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

 \begin{document}
 \section{test}
 \citep{ bender:1975, bender:1968, bender:1974}\\
 \citet{ bender:1975, bender:1968, bender:1974}

   \printbibliography

 \end{document}
```

[image]