# BibLaTeX: Some entries show author field as a dash (-)

Tags: biblatex

I am observing a strange effect in BibLaTeX. When I have two papers printed in succession that do have the same author (see example below) I get only a dash (-) in the second reference where the author is supposed to be printed.

What is that and where in the manual can I read more about this (I can personally not imagine why anybody wants such a behaviour)?

I would like that authors are always printed regardless if they where mentioned or listed before before or depending on the environment of the citation...

Here a self-contained example:

```
\documentclass{article}

% BibLaTeX
\usepackage[
  backend=bibtex,
  style=authoryear,
  firstinits=true,
  maxbibnames=99]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}


\begin{document}

\nocite{Meyer1,Meyer2}

\setlength\bibitemsep{5pt}
\printbibheading[title={Bibliography}]
\printbibliography[type=article, heading=subbibliography, title={Journals}]

\end{document}
```

And the bib file:

```
@article{Meyer1,
  author = {Meyer, Bob},
  title = {{Some Great Paper}},
  journal = {Some Great Journal},
  volume = {9},
  year = {2015},
  pages = {99--109},
  issue = {9},
  doi = {99.9999/99999-999-9999-9},
}

@article{Meyer2,
  author = {Meyer, Bob},
  title = {{EAnother Great Paper}},
  journal = {Another Great Journal},
  year = {2015},
  volume = {9},
  pages = {99-109},
  number = {9},
  doi = {88.8888/8888888.8888888}
}
```

Comment: I can perfectly imagine why one may want such a formatting: it's easy to spot at once how many authors are referenced. It is just one of the traditional styles.

Comment: Its only working if authors are sorted in direct succession. If the same author appears again further down the list, he or she is printed normal again. So I really don't think its very useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has already been asked here:

[Get full name twice in Bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49140/get-full-name-twice-in-bibliography)

The solution is loading `biblatex` with `dashed=false`