# Remove the ——— in the bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I have inherited a latex stylesheet and document, in it, the bibliography seems to detect when there are multiple works in a row, with the same author, when this occurs it replaces the author with a line, i.e:

> Crisp, Oliver. Divinity and Humanity. New York: Cambridge, 2007.
>   ——— God Incarnate. New York: T&T Clark, 2009.
>   ——— The Word Enfleshed: Exploring the Person and Work of Christ. TBC: TBC, 2016.

I wonder if anyone can point me in the right direction to start working out how to get rid of this behaviour? I notice there is this in the `.sty` file:

```
\setlength\bibindent{\parindent}

\renewcommand\@openbib@code{%
        \setstretch{1}
        \singlespacing
        \setlength\leftmargin{\bibindent}
        \setlength\itemindent{-\bibindent}
        \addtolength\itemindent{\labelsep}
        \addtolength\itemindent{\labelwidth}
        \setlength\itemsep{\tf@singlelineskip}
        \setlength\parsep{\z@}}

% set formatting defaults and pass options
\PassOptionsToPackage%
        {isbn=false, autolang=other, footmarkoff, backend=biber}%
        {biblatex-chicago}
\if@authordateformat
        \PassOptionsToPackage{authordate}{biblatex-chicago}
\fi

%  adjustments to \printbibliography formatting
\if@appendbibformat
        \AtEndPreamble{%
                \@ifpackageloaded{biblatex}%
                        {%
                                \if@authordateformat
                                        \DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
                                                bibliography = {References}}
                                \else
                                        \DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
                                                references = {Bibliography}}
                                \fi
                                \renewcommand{\bibsetup}{%
                                        \addcontentsline{toc}{\tf@topsecname}{\bibname}
                                        \singlespacing}
                                \renewcommand{\bibitemsep}{1\baselineskip}
                                \renewcommand{\bibhang}{0.5in}
                        }{}}
\fi
```

Comment: Please note that often it is very important to know which style you are using. With questions like this it is a very, very good idea to provide an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) so that we can see what style you are using and what other set-up you have, we can then also test our suggestions with for your specific situation making sure that they work for you.

Comment: For other styles, see [Get full name twice in Bibliography](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49140/35864)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using the SBL style `biblatex-sbl` try

```
\AtBeginBibliography{\renewbibmacro{dashcheck}[2]{#2}}
```

alternatively, you could also go with

```
\renewbibmacro*{bbx:dashcheck}[2]{#2}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 \usepackage[...,dashed=false]{biblatex}
```

Comment: When I add it, it is now, `\usepackage[style=sbl,backend=biber,dashed=false]{biblatex}`
but that doesn't compile. However, it does give me a clue as to where to look in the documentation! Thanks

Comment: by the way: `backend=biber` is the default

Comment: BTW, there's a good reason the `dashed=false` package option doesn't work... It was only implemented recently and is only available in the development version of `biblatex-sbl`, not the one in CTAN. If you need the development version you can grab it from https://github.com/dcpurton/biblatex-sbl/tree/dev (It will be a little while before I get to the next release.)