# Remove dash for repeated author in biblatex-chicago

Tags: biblatex, chicago-style, biblatex-chicago

for my seminar paper, I have to quote a scientific paper. This is the corresponding `.bib` entry:

```
@article{hochreiter1991untersuchungen,
  title={Untersuchungen zu dynamischen neuronalen Netzen},
  author={Sepp Hochreiter},
  journal={Diploma, Technische Universit{\"a}t M{\"u}nchen},
  volume={91},
  number={1},
  year={1991}
}
```

In my bibliography, however, the scientific paper appears as follows

> — . 1991. „Untersuchungen zu dynamischen neuronalen Netzen“. Diploma,
>   Technische Universität München 91 (1).

The problem is that the author is replaced by a dash. Does anyone know where the error in my bibtext is?

Comment: Add the option `dashed=false` to your `biblatex` loading options.

Comment: My mistake, I forgot to mention that I use Sharelatex. So I only have one literatur.bib and a main.tex file.
Where is the loading optins in Sharelatex?

Comment: I meant the `biblatex` options. You should have `\usepackage[...]{biblatex}` somewhere. Add `dashed=false` to the `...` in square brackets in that line.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49140/35864

Comment: Do you mean like this?
`\usepackage[style=chicago-authordate,natbib=true,backend=biber,dashed=false]{biblatex}`

Unfortunately I get the following error with it
`/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty, line 13053
Package keyval Error: dashed undefined.
See the keyval package documentation for explanation. Type H <return> for immediate help. ... l.13053 \blx@processoptions Try typing <return> to proceed. If that doesn't work, type X <return> to quit.`

Comment: Aha! The dash feature is style dependent, `chicago-authordate` does not have such an option. The CMS wants that dash.

Comment: So is there no way to fix the bug without changing the style? Unfortunately the style for my seminar paper is given.

Comment: Thing is: It's not a bug, it's a feature. The dash is what the Chicago Manual of Style wants for repeated authors.

Comment: So that's what it's supposed to be? Okay then I'll leave it that way. Thanks!!

Comment: You *can* change it as shown below, but there is no convenient interface for that. That is mainly because the CMS wants the dash.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Update (March 2021)**

In version 2.1 (2021-03-27), `biblatex-chicago` introduced the `dashed` option which can be set to `false` to print repeated names in the bibliography (just like in `biblatex`'s standard `authoryear` style).

```latex
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[authordate, backend=biber, dashed=false]{biblatex-chicago}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\autocite{knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-chicago/doc/biblatex-chicago.pdf) now explains (for v2.3a on p. 73 in §4.4.2 *Pre-Set `chicago` Options*):

> Constanza Cordoni has requested a way to turn off the 3-em dash for replacing repeated names in the bibliography, and the *Manual* admits that some publishers prefer this, as the
> dash can carry with it certain inconveniences, especially for electronic formats (14.67). Some of `biblatex`’s standard styles have a `dashed` option, so for compatibility purposes I’ve provided the same. By default I have set it to print the name dash, but you can set
> `dashed=false` globally, per type, or per entry to repeat names as and when required.

---

**Solution for older releases**

In the standard styles you could turn off the dash with the option `dashed=false`, see [Get full name twice in Bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49140/35864).

The styles of `biblatex-chicago` do not know that option and do not allow you to turn the dash off easily. It is a feature of the Chicago Manual of Style bibliography styles that they replace subsequent mentions of the same author list with a dash.

Since there is no option to turn off the dash, there is no convenient way to get rid of it, you need to play with internal macros. You can essentially tell `biblatex` to forget who the last author was by undefining `\bbx@lasthash`, which forces the style to never use the dash to replace the name.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[authordate,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
\AtEveryBibitem{\global\undef\bbx@lasthash}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\cite{knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: bibliography of the MWE: both entries show the full author name, there is no dash]

Please note that the styles of `biblatex-chicago` should ideally be loaded using the wrapper package `biblatex-chicago` and not the normal `biblatex` package (as shown in the MWE). But then you can't use the `natbib` option.

Answer (score 1):

The following source:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[authordate,strict,backend=biber,bibencoding=inputenc]{biblatex-chicago}

\addbibresource{test.bib} % contains the .bib record originally posted 
\begin{document}

    \nocite{*}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

... [image]produces this result:

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. It is pretty hard to find a question to answer as a new member. Unfortunately, your answer does not answer the question or gives any useful insights.

Comment: I beg to disagree. The question was "Does anyone know where the error in my bibtext is?"  My answer shows the proper code using the original .bib record to provide the bibliography desired.

Comment: The error/reason that produces the dash and how to get rid of it. You do not address that.

Comment: With all due respect, Johannes_B, my answer demonstrates that there is no error. The original post shows a single .bib record and my answer demonstrates that it typesets correctly. The bibliography style itself imposes the dash for additional bibliographies by the same author. The original post showed only a single record and a single output. Comments under the post reveal that others were unaware of the bibliography style features. So it appears there were problems in the original post.

Comment: The answer is technically correct (the best kind of correct) especially taking into account the wording of the question. But it does not address the underlying issue behind the question (the question-as-intended, the question-as-it-should-have-been). Unfortunately, the question does not include an MWE that properly reproduces the *actual* issue the OP is complaining about, namely that in a subsequent work of the same author the name is replaced by a dash. Obviously that problem only shows when there are several `.bib` entries. ...

Comment: ... In cases like this where the information in the question is clearly not enough to reproduce the problematic behaviour, it might be nice to go for a more charitable reading of the question that tries to uncover what's actually behind the issue instead of answering at face value, but I'd say that decision is entirely up to you.