# How to customize the order of entry elements for biblatex-chicago?

Tags: bibliographies, biblatex-chicago

I'm a newbie in latex and not very familiar with the latex ecosystem. For a homework for university we have to use a specific [chicage-style](https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/tools_citationguide/citation-guide-2.html) for our bibliography. I choosed biblatex-chicago for dealing with that.

Now I have two concerns:

- biblatex-chicago puts the year nearly at the end of the entry in round braces but we are expected to put the year behind the author
- biblatex-chicago replaces the author of following entries if its the same author like the first with a line, again we aren't supposed to do that

**Some code**:

```
\usepackage{bibgerm}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[notes,natbib,isbn=false,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{general.bib}
@article{PIC85,
    year        = {1985},
    journal     = {Die Betriebswirtschaft},
    number      = {45},
    publisher   = {C.E.Poeschel Verlag Stuttgart},
    title       = {Transaktionskosten},
    author      = {Arnold Picot},
    pages       = {224--225},
    urn         = {urn:nbn:de:bvb:19-epub-6853-8},
}

@article{PIC86,
    journal     = {Der Betriebsberater},
    year        = {1986},
    number      = {27, Be},
    publisher   = {Recht und Wirtschaft GmbH},
    title       = {Transaktionskosten im Handel},
    author      = {Arnold Picot},
    pages       = {1--16},
    url         = {https://doi.org/10.5282/ubm/epub.6845},
}
\end{filecontents} 
\bibliography{general}
```

**With the output being**:

[image]

**What I expect**:

- Picot, Arnold. 1985. "Transaktionskosten" [...]
- Picot, Arnold. 1986. "Transaktionskosten im Handel" [...]

**My Question**:

Is this even feasible? Or should I use a different package? Or should I just do it manually?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: In general it is preferred to post fully compilable code instead of snippets. It is quite simple to turn the code you posted so far into a compilable document, but it would be appreciated if you could post a complete and compilable example. With `biblatex` you shouldn't have to load `bibgerm`. If you write German following the *neue Rechtschreibung* you may want to load `babel` with the option `ngerman` instead of `german`.

Comment: What should citations in the text look like? Should they be in 'author-year' format or full note citations?

Comment: Thank you for that reminder, I will update that code block tomorrow.

Comment: And yes, author-year is what is asked from us. Like (Picot 1985, 224) to give an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it by myself. Like moewe commented, babel has to be loaded with ngerman.
This moved the date in the entries of references to the desired position.

```
\usepackage{bibgerm}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, authordate, eprint=false, url=false, bibencoding=inputenc, noibid]{biblatex-chicago}
```

For the second part with the dashed line for repeating authors I found a fix, by also moewe: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/455528

Comment: Don't load `\usepackage{bibgerm}` with `biblatex` or `biblatex-chicago`. I'd also suggest not to set `bibencoding=inputenc,` as the value `inputenc` is deprecated and is now called `auto` and `bibencoding=auto` is the predefined value anyway.