# Names should repeat instead of three emdash rule using biblatex-chicago and biber

Tags: biblatex-chicago

My codes are follows:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[natbib,authordate,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}%

\addbibresource{bibsamp.bib}

\begin{document}

\citet{baker_tenenbaum_saxe06} and \citet{baker_saxe_tenenbaum09}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

**Content of test.bib**

```
@inproceedings{baker_tenenbaum_saxe06,
Author = {C. L. Baker and J. Tenenbaum and R. Saxe},
Booktitle = {Advances in Neural Information Processing Systems},
Date-Added = {2014-01-30 12:16:28 +0100},
Date-Modified = {2014-02-01 00:11:49 +0100},
Publisher = {Cambridge, MA: MIT Press},
Title = {Bayesian Models of Human Action Understanding},
Volume = {18},
Year = {2006}}

@article{baker_saxe_tenenbaum09,
Author = {C. L. Baker and J. Tenenbaum and R. Saxe},
Date-Added = {2014-01-30 12:11:35 +0100},
Date-Modified = {2014-02-05 23:44:19 +0100},
Journal = {Cognition},
Number = {3},
Pages = {329--349},
Title = {Action Understanding as Inverse Planning},
Volume = {113},
Year = {2009}}
```

**Output**
[image]

I need to repeat the author names instead of three em dash rule even though the author names are same.

Please suggest...

Comment: Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/455523/35864 help?

Comment: @moewe How great you are!!! so fast and accurate.....This exactly solved my problem.....Salute....