# How do you remove the letters from the end of duplicate author year biblatex citations? (Biblatex-chicago with bibtex)

Tags: cv, biblatex-chicago

I am building a cv wherein I `\printbibliography` for given `keywords` for several sections. Some of the sections have 100+ bibliography entries, and there are several occasions where there are the same author and year. This is a stripped-down version of the code.

```
\usepackage[style=chicago-authordate, backend=bibtex, maxbibnames=50, doi=true, url=true, isbn=false, sorting=ydnt]{biblatex}

\bibliography{sample.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\section{A}
\printbibliography[keyword={keywordA}, heading=none]

\section{B}
\printbibliography[keyword={keywordB}, heading=none]

\end{document}
```

Of course, the bibliography prints those entries as "Author. YEARa." e.g.,

Taylor, Sarah and Joe Hoya. 2010a. "Here's one article title."

-- 2010b. "This is a different article."

-- 2010c. "A third article."

**But I need it to look like this:**

Taylor, Sarah and Joe Hoya. 2010. "Here's one article title."

-- 2010. "This is a different article."

-- 2010. "A third article."

**or this:**

Taylor, Sarah and Joe Hoya. 2010. "Here's one article title."

Taylor, Sarah and Joe Hoya. 2010. "This is a different article."

Taylor, Sarah and Joe Hoya. 2010. "A third article."

---

Is this possible? Especially while using `\printbibliography`?

Answer (score 0):

When I turn your code into an MWE I do not get any letters after dates, but the dates are moved to the end of the entry. That is with `biblatex-chicago` v2.1 (2021-03-27).

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[
  backend=bibtex,
  style=chicago-authordate,
  sorting=ydnt,
  maxbibnames=50,
  doi=true, url=true, isbn=false,
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b,knuth:ct:c,sigfridsson,worman,geer}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Knuth, Donald E. TeX: The Program. Vol. B of Computers & Typesetting. Reading, Mass.: Addison-Wesley, 1986.]

This is due to the fact that in the example, the `biblatex-chicago` style is loaded directly via `biblatex` and not as recommended for `biblatex-chicago` via the wrapper package.

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[
  authordate,
  backend=bibtex,
  sorting=ydnt,
  maxbibnames=50,
  doi=true, url=true, isbn=false,
]{biblatex-chicago}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b,knuth:ct:c,sigfridsson,worman,geer}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Knuth, Donald E. 1986a. TeX: The Program. Vol. B of Computers & Typesetting. Reading, Mass.: Addison-Wesley.]

It is possible that older versions of `biblatex-chicago` behaved slightly differently, so that the date letter (courtesy of `labeldateparts`) is also present when the style is not called via `biblatex-chicago`.

Here is a solution that works with my newer version of `biblatex-chicago`, but it should also work for older versions. The idea is to just discard the `extradate` info.

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[
  authordate,
  backend=bibtex,
  sorting=ydnt,
  maxbibnames=50,
  doi=true, url=true, isbn=false,
]{biblatex-chicago}

\DeclareFieldInputHandler{extradate}{\def\NewValue{}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b,knuth:ct:c,sigfridsson,worman,geer}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Knuth, Donald E. 1986. TeX: The Program. Vol. B of Computers & Typesetting. Reading, Mass.: Addison-Wesley.]

Comment: Amazing, that worked! Is there also an easy solution to change the ------ to repeat author's name? As in making the Knuth citations  

Knuth, Donald E. 1986. _TEX: The Program._ ...
Knuth, Donald E. 1986. _The METAFONTbook._ ...

Comment: @TrellaceLawrimore https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/455523/35864