# How to modify biblatex ABNT style - URL; DOI

Tags: biblatex, abnt, abntex2

Based in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/495844/how-to-modify-the-biblatex-abnt-style) I wrote the follow MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}

\usepackage[style=abnt-numeric, backend = biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\bibstring{urlfrom}\addcolon\addspace<\normalfont\url{#1}>}%

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{website:ArduinoLabview,
  author  = {{National Instruments}},
  title   = {Arduino Compatible Compiler for LabVIEW by Aledyne-TSXperts},
  year    = {2019},
  url     = {https://www.tsxperts.com/arduino-compatible-compiler-for-labview/},
  urldate = {2019-06-07},
}

\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{website:ArduinoLabview}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

How to change the URL and DOI font to normal style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`biblatex` delegates URL and DOI formatting to the `url` package, so you can use its interfaces to change the URL font to the normal document font

```
\urlstyle{same}
```

There is no need for the `\normalfont` and it won't do anything anyway, so the redefinition of the `url` field format can be dropped.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}

\usepackage[style=abnt-numeric, backend = biber]{biblatex}

\urlstyle{same}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{website:ArduinoLabview,
  author  = {{National Instruments}},
  title   = {Arduino Compatible Compiler for LabVIEW by Aledyne-TSXperts},
  year    = {2019},
  url     = {https://www.tsxperts.com/arduino-compatible-compiler-for-labview/},
  urldate = {2019-06-07},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{website:ArduinoLabview}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: "NATIONAL INSTRUMENTS. Arduino Compatible Compiler for LabVIEW by Aledyne-TSXperts. [S.l.: s.n.], 2019. Disponível em: <https://www.tsxperts.com/arduino-compatible-compiler-for-labview/>. Acesso em: 7 jun. 2019." with URL in normal document font.]