# Citations without numbers

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing

in the last second I realized we shouldn't have numbers in our bibliography (such [1]  Smith, J. ..). The bibliography is created with \printbibliography in the biblatex environment.

As I'm in an extreme hurry I hope someone has a solution/hint without a MWE, otherwise I'll update that.

Thanks a lot!

/Edit: That's a (not very short) MWE and I'm not sure how to include the external bib.-file, thats why I posted it seperately. Hope that's fine! Thanks again

```
%Dokumentklasse
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[left= 3cm,right = 3cm, top = 2.5cm, bottom = 2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
% ============= Packages =============

%test
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  style=section,% <- change the style to section
  indent=0pt,
  beforeskip=1.5cm,
  afterindent=false,
  afterskip=1cm
]{chapter}



% Dokumentinformationen
\usepackage[
    pdftitle={xxx},
    pdfsubject={},
    pdfauthor={xxx},
    pdfkeywords={}, 
    %Links nicht einrahmen
    hidelinks
]{hyperref}


% Standard Packages
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx, subfig}
\graphicspath{{img/}}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{color}

% zusätzliche Schriftzeichen der American Mathematical Society
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}

%nicht einrücken nach Absatz
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

%Abkürzungsverzeichnis
\usepackage{acronym}

%biblatex
\usepackage[backend=biber,citestyle=authoryear, maxcitenames=2, sorting=nyt]{biblatex}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{andothers={et\ al\adddot}} % aus u.a. zu et al. machen
\addbibresource{Quellenverzeichnis.bib}

%captions
\usepackage[font=small,skip=2pt]{caption}

%times new roman
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}

%Arabische und Romanische Numerierung
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{equation}{chapter}

%Abbildungszählweise
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}

%Excel2Latex packages
\usepackage{booktabs, multicol, multirow}

%appendix
\usepackage{appendix}

%adjust caption font size
\usepackage{caption}

%tabellenunterschrift
\usepackage{threeparttable}

%rotieren tabelle
\usepackage{rotating}

%cellcolor
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{array}

%rand vermeiden
\usepackage{microtype}% 

%%%%%%%Dokumentenbeginn%%%%%

\begin{document}
lalala \textcite{Black}

\newpage
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

and the bib.file:

```
@article{Black,
  title={The capital asset pricing model: Some empirical tests},
  author={Black, Fischer and Jensen, Michael C and Scholes, Myron and others},
  journal={Studies in the theory of capital markets},
  volume={81},
  number={3},
  pages={79--121},
  year={1972},
  publisher={Praeger, New York}
}
```

Comment: How do you want to cite in your document? You can just try something like `style=authoryear,`, but without knowing what you want (we only know that you don't want numbers) and what you are doing (an MWE) we can't really say anything useful.

Comment: Very similar post on golatex: https://golatex.de/literaturverzeichnis-ohne-numerierung-t22623.html

Comment: yes, due to my time pressure I posted it on both pages. I just updated the mwe, it's not ideal but should work (except the bib.file, I'm sorry about that)

Comment: You probably want `style=authoryear,` instead of `citestyle=authoryear,`.

Comment: thanks for the fast reply. Unfortunately, while the numbers are gone some of the author names are replaced by "-" and the citations are listed with almost no gap between them

Comment: `dahed=false`. Since there is an indentation you don't actually need gaps between the entries, but you can get them with `\setlength{\bibitemsep}{\itemsep}` or some such. I'm just writing an answer.

Comment: worked perfectly, although it should be "dashed=false" instead. Thanks a lot for your prompt help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually one passes the desired style to `biblatex` with the `style` option, e.g.

```
style=authoryear,
```

But the code in the question says only `citestyle=authoryear,` and thus only sets the citation style.

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, citestyle=authoryear, maxcitenames=2, sorting=nyt]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Bibliography with numbers.]

To understand what that does we need to understand a bit more about `biblatex` styles.

A `biblatex` style usually consists of two parts

1. the citation style and
2. the bibliography style.

The citation style controls how works are cited in the text (the result of `\autocite`, `\cite`, `\parencite`, ...) and the bibliography style controls the presentation in the bibliography (the result of `\printbibliography`). Sometimes there are dependencies between the two (for example with `\fullcite`, which is a citation command, but it prints the full bibliography entry as define by the bibliography style).

In general it is possible to set these two aspects of a style separately with `citestyle` and `bibstyle`. Not all styles support this completely, some custom styles have bibliography and citation styles that are so intertwined that they can only be used together. So for almost all intents and purposes one is better off just setting the option `style`, which sets both `citestyle` and `bibstyle` to the same value.

The default setting if you don't give any `...style` option to `biblatex` is

```
style=numeric,
```

which is equivalent to

```
bibstyle=numeric, citestyle=numeric,
```

If we only load `biblatex` with the option `citestyle=authoryear`, that overrides the default `citestyle` setting and we end up with

```
bibstyle=numeric, citestyle=authoryear,
```

This means you get author-year citations, but a numeric bibliography. This is general not what people expect or want (the numbers in the numeric bibliography don't correspond to anything useful in the document, so they are just noise).

You probably want

```
style=authoryear,
```

to get a consistent style in both citations and the bibliography. Note that that option automatically sets `sorting=nyt,`, so that ca be dropped. In the comments it emerged that you also want `dashed=false` ([Get full name twice in Bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49140/35864)) and want to set `\bibitemsep` to a non-zero value.

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear, maxcitenames=2, dashed=false]{biblatex}

\setlength{\bibitemsep}{\itemsep}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,nussbaum}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Bibliography without numbers.]

Comment: again, thanks a lot for your fast help!