# Biblatex: Print author names in reference list for non-unique authors

Tags: biblatex

My references contain two elements with the same author names and year in them. Using `style=authoryear`, they are listed as "Authors, 2009a" and "Authors, 2009b" in the text which is fine for me. However, In the reference section, the author field of the second entry seem to be replaced with an em-dash (`—`). I already tried to find a corresponding field that I can change with `\DeclareFieldFormat`, but had no luck. How can I change this so that both entries list the author names.

**Example output:**
[image: How it looks like]

**And this is how I want it to be (note how both entries for Alam, A. have full author information):**
[image: How it should look like]

**Example code:**

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents*}{mybib.bib}
@article{alam2009a,
  title = {High-Resolution Structure of the Open {{NaK}} Channel},
  author = {Alam, Amer and Jiang, Youxing},
  date = {2009-01-21},
  journaltitle = {Nature Structural \& Molecular Biology},
  volume = {16},
  pages = {30--34},
  doi = {10.1038/nsmb.1531},
  keywords = {\#nosource},
  number = {1}
}

@article{alam2009b,
  title = {Structural Analysis of Ion Selectivity in the {{NaK}} Channel},
  author = {Alam, Amer and Jiang, Youxing},
  date = {2009-01},
  journaltitle = {Nature Structural \& Molecular Biology},
  volume = {16},
  pages = {35--41},
  doi = {10.1038/nsmb.1537},
  langid = {english},
  number = {1}
}

@article{altomare2001,
  title = {Integrated {{Allosteric Model}} of {{Voltage Gating}} of {{Hcn Channels}}},
  author = {Altomare, Claudia and Bucchi, Annalisa and Camatini, Eva and Baruscotti, Mirko and Viscomi, Carlo and Moroni, Anna and DiFrancesco, Dario},
  date = {2001-06-01},
  journaltitle = {The Journal of General Physiology},
  shortjournal = {J Gen Physiol},
  volume = {117},
  pages = {519--532},
  number = {6},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[
    style=authoryear,
    doi=false,
    backref,
    giveninits=true,
    uniquelist=false,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}

% newline after author and year
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\newline\bibsentence}

\begin{document}
This is a document that cites \cite{alam2009a} and \cite{alam2009b} and has a
reference from \cite{altomare2001}.
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you want the option `dashed=false,`? (See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49140/35864)

Comment: Yes. Thank you! Do you want to post this as an answer so I can accept it?