# Printing authors name not working

Tags: bibliographies, biber

I am citing a few manuals from a company (ARM) in a thesis. I created thema as manuals in my bib file but in some cases (which I don't understand) the author will not be displayed correctly in the bibliography.
Two examples:

```
@Manual{Limited2020c,
  title      = {Platform Security Requirements 1.0},
  author     = {{Arm Limited}},
  month      = oct,
  note       = {Version 1.0},
  year       = {2020},
  readstatus = {read},
}

@Manual{Limited2020,
  title      = {ARM Server Base System Architecture 6.0 - Platform Design Document},
  author     = {{Arm Limited}},
  note       = {Version 6.0},
  year       = {2020},
  readstatus = {read},
}
```

So it seems to be very similar (not to say it looks same...), but in my document the first author is not printed while the author of the second entry gets is printed:

[image: Screenshot]

Any idea why the hell it results in this scenario?

Comment: Some bibliography styles replace names with dashes if they are the same as in the previous entry. If and how that can be turned off depends on the bibliography style you are using. Please tell us about your bibliography style and setup - ideally in the form of a small example document (complete but as short as possible with `\documentclass`, a preamble and `\begin{document}...\end{document}`) that reproduces the output from the screenshot with as little code as possible.

Comment: If you are using one of the `biblatex` standard styles and see dashes, you can most likely turn off this behaviour with the option `dashed=false,`. (See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49140/35864) But this option is not supported by all third party styles and not even by the standard styles in case dashes are never used (`numeric`, `alphabetic` and friends). What exactly works for you depends on the style you are using.

Comment: @moewe oh boy, thanks a lot for this hint. Never heard about this. It works, with `dashed=false` or I just take another style.
If you post this as an answer, I will accept it!

Comment: If `dashed=false,` works, this question is probably just a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49140/35864. If it does not work, it might still be possibly to disable the dash somehow, but it might be trickier.