# How do you disable en and em dash ligatures in a biblatex/biber bibliography?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber, ligatures, biblatex-mla

I am trying to write an MLA conforming paper with LaTeX for a school assignment, but I have a very strict professor when it comes to bibliography formatting. Specifically, my issue is that BibLaTeX/Biber appears to be printing three connected dashes when listing two works by the same author, which causes them to look like one long dash instead of three separate ones. I am guessing that this is a ligature feature that runs automatically inside `\printbibliography`, but when I tried calling `\usepackage{microtype}` and `\DisableLigatures{}` in the preamble, it only affected dashes outside of the bibliography.

If possible, I would like to only disable this en/em dash feature inside the `\printbibliography` command.

Here is what I am currently getting: [image: three connected dashes]
And here is what is shown on the MLA website: [image: three disconnected dashes]

Here's a simple example:

- Test.tex:

```tex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

% Mla and bibliography support.
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage{mla}
\usepackage[style=mla-new,backend=biber]{biblatex}

% Add bibliography here.
\addbibresource{Test.bib}
\defbibheading{bibliography}{\center Works Cited}

\begin{document}
\begin{mla}{First Name}{Last Name}{Professor}{Course Name}{\today}{Title}
    Sentence 1 \autocite{the_editors_of_encyclopaedia_britannica_henry_2023}.
    Sentence 2 \autocite{the_editors_of_encyclopaedia_britannica_mexican-american_2023}.

    \newpage
    \printbibliography

\end{mla}
\end{document}
```

- Test.bib

```tex
@inreference{the_editors_of_encyclopaedia_britannica_henry_2023,
    title = {Henry David Thoreau},
    url = {https://www.britannica.com/biography/Henry-David-Thoreau},
    abstract = {Henry David Thoreau, American essayist, poet, and practical philosopher renowned for having lived the doctrines of Transcendentalism as recorded in his masterwork, Walden (1854), and for having been a vigorous advocate of civil liberties, as evidenced in the essay ‘Civil Disobedience’ (1849).},
    booktitle = {Encyclopedia Britannica},
    author = {{The Editors of Encyclopaedia Britannica}},
    date = {2023-07-08},
    langid = {english},
    file = {Snapshot:/home/cachandler/Productivity/Zotero/storage/I2SMT29Q/Henry-David-Thoreau.html:text/html},
}

@inreference{the_editors_of_encyclopaedia_britannica_mexican-american_2023,
    title = {Mexican-American War},
    url = {https://www.britannica.com/event/Mexican-American-War},
    abstract = {Mexican-American War, war between the U.S. and Mexico from 1846 to 1848. It was caused by a territorial dispute stemming from the United States’ annexation of Texas in 1845 and from contention over whether Texas ended at the Nueces River or the Rio Grande.},
    booktitle = {Encyclopedia Britannica},
    author = {{The Editors of Encyclopaedia Britannica}},
    date = {2023-06-19},
    langid = {english},
    file = {Snapshot:/home/cachandler/Productivity/Zotero/storage/R4S2NAND/Mexican-American-War.html:text/html},
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Get full name twice in Bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49140/5764)

Comment: Please show us a small example document that reproduces the status quo. We need to know exactly how the dashes are produced in order to help you change them. It should be noted that it is very possible that the MLA wants the three dashes to look like a single dash in print, but that the typography on the website cannot make that happen and renders as three single dashes, so you may want to double-check with the official requirements in the official format.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. What are you using to produce the bibliography, and have you asked whether the solid dash is unacceptable to your professor? The idea that there are professors like that is incredibly depressing.

Comment: (I fully agree with @AlanMunn's sentiment.) As a practical (though tedious) remedy, could you open the bbl file in a text editor once you're fully done with the bibliography and hand-edit the `---------` instances to your adviser's liking, say to `---\kern0.5pt---\kern0.5pt---`?

Comment: @moewe I have now added a small example to my post.

Comment: @AlanMunn I use Zotero to generate the `.bib` files, and then include them in my latex document with `\usepackage[style=mla-new,backend=biber]{biblatex}`. As for my instructor, unfortunately this is one of the professors that keeps the MLA handbook next to his desk while grading to make sure students didn't miss anything.

@Mico I'm currently looking at the bbl file, but I don't see anywhere where I would be able to hand edit the dashes. Both `\name{author}` tags appear to have the full `The Editors...` entry.

Comment: @Werner I saw that page earlier while looking online for a solution, but the issue is that MLA requires the three dashes for the author entry whenever the works cited page has two texts by the same person.

Comment: I suppose I could manually edit the PDF file with Libreoffice Draw after the fact though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be interested in the `longdash` option of `biblatex-mla`. [The documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-mla/doc/biblatex-mla.pdf) explains

> The 9th edition of the *MLA Handbook* clarifies that dashes indicating multiple entries by one author can either be styled with three em-dashes or three hyphens. From version 2.0, output defaults to em-dashes, but setting `longdash` to false reverts back to hyphens:
>
> ```
> \usepackage[style=mla,longdash=false]{biblatex}
> ```

So you may want to try

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage{mla}
\usepackage[style=mla-new,backend=biber,longdash=false]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inreference{the_editors_of_encyclopaedia_britannica_henry_2023,
    title = {Henry David Thoreau},
    url = {https://www.britannica.com/biography/Henry-David-Thoreau},
    abstract = {Henry David Thoreau, American essayist, poet, and practical philosopher renowned for having lived the doctrines of Transcendentalism as recorded in his masterwork, Walden (1854), and for having been a vigorous advocate of civil liberties, as evidenced in the essay ‘Civil Disobedience’ (1849).},
    booktitle = {Encyclopedia Britannica},
    author = {{The Editors of Encyclopaedia Britannica}},
    date = {2023-07-08},
    langid = {english},
    file = {Snapshot:/home/cachandler/Productivity/Zotero/storage/I2SMT29Q/Henry-David-Thoreau.html:text/html},
}
@inreference{the_editors_of_encyclopaedia_britannica_mexican-american_2023,
    title = {Mexican-American War},
    url = {https://www.britannica.com/event/Mexican-American-War},
    abstract = {Mexican-American War, war between the U.S. and Mexico from 1846 to 1848. It was caused by a territorial dispute stemming from the United States’ annexation of Texas in 1845 and from contention over whether Texas ended at the Nueces River or the Rio Grande.},
    booktitle = {Encyclopedia Britannica},
    author = {{The Editors of Encyclopaedia Britannica}},
    date = {2023-06-19},
    langid = {english},
    file = {Snapshot:/home/cachandler/Productivity/Zotero/storage/R4S2NAND/Mexican-American-War.html:text/html},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\defbibheading{bibliography}{\center Works Cited}

\begin{document}
\begin{mla}{First Name}{Last Name}{Professor}{Course Name}{\today}{Title}
    Sentence 1 \autocite{the_editors_of_encyclopaedia_britannica_henry_2023}.
    Sentence 2 \autocite{the_editors_of_encyclopaedia_britannica_mexican-american_2023}.

    \newpage
    \printbibliography

\end{mla}
\end{document}
```

[image: The Editors of Encyclopaedia Britannica. “Henry David Thoreau.” Encyclopedia Britannica, 8 July 2023, www.britannica.com/biography/Henry-David-Thoreau. ---. “Mexican-American War.” Encyclopedia Britannica, 19 June 2023, www.britannica.com/event/Mexican-American-War.]

---

If you prefer em-dashes with spaces between them try

```
\renewcommand*{\mlanamedash}{\textemdash\kern 1pt\textemdash\kern 1pt\textemdash}

\renewcommand*{\bibnamedash}{%
  \printtext[noformat]{\mlanamedash}
  \iffieldundef{nameaddon}%
    {\setunit{\addperiod\addspace}}%
    {\setunit{\nopunct}}}%
```

I had to add a non-negative kern to get spaces between them, but I suspect that if and the extent to which this is necessary depends also on the font you use, so you might want to play around with the `\kern 1pt` here.