# Change definition of \sameauthors to turn off by same dash

Tags: bibtex, amsrefs

I am using the `amsplain` style for the bibliography, but I do not want the dash instead of the names of duplicated authors.

I found this post [Is it normal for BibTeX to replace similar author names with "------"?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29381/is-it-normal-for-bibtex-to-replace-similar-author-names-with) for IEEEtran style.

The `amsref` documentation says

> Change the definition of `\sameauthors` if you don’t want to get a bysame dash.

How can I change the definition of `\sameauthors` command or do something similar to the post for `amsrefs`?

Edit: I am not using the amsrefs package. I only have a bib database and the lines:

```
\bibliographystyle{amsplain}

\bibliography{mybibfile}
```

If I add `\usepackage{amsrefs}` (thinking about using the `nobysame` option), I get lots of errors and the bibliography is not generated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are using the `amsrefs` package, then you can turn off the dash with a package option. From the documentation:

> 6.4 Miscellaneous Options
>
> **nobysame:** If two or more consecutive bibliography items have the same
>   authors, amsrefs will normally replace the author names in the
>   second and succeeding entries by a horizontal rule (_ _ _ _ _). This option
>   disables this feature, causing the full author names to always be
>   printed.

If you are just using the `amsplain.bst` as a bibliography style, you will need to make a new version of the `.bst` file that doesn't print the dash.  Here are instructions for editing the `.bst` file.  (I'll assume a TeXLive installation).

Open `/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/amscls/amsplain.bst`

Inside you will find the following function around line 367.

```
FUNCTION {format.authors}
{ author empty$
    { "" }
    { bysame "\bysame" =
         {"\bysame"}
         { author format.names }
     if$
    }
  if$
}
```

Change this to:

```
FUNCTION {format.authors}
    { author format.names }
```

Then save the file as `amsplain-nodash.bst` in a place where TeX can find it.  If this is for a single document, you could save it in the same folder as the document. If you want to use this more generally, save it in `<path-to-local-texmf>/texmf/bibtex/bst/` and then you can use it with any document.

Then in your document, use:

```
\bibliographystyle{amsplain-nodash}
```

Comment: I think I maybe asked the wrong question (because I am confused). I am not actually using the amsrefs package. I edited the question.

Answer (score 2):

If you use amsrefs, try to add this

`\usepackage[nobysame]{amsrefs}`

A short example

```
\documentclass[twoside]{amsart}
\usepackage[alphabetic]{amsrefs}

\begin{document}
\begin{bibdiv}
\begin{biblist}
\bib{Gan1}{article}
{author={Gan}}

\bib{Gan2}{article}
{author={Gan}}
\end{biblist}
\end{bibdiv}

\end{document}
```

If you compile the above code, you will get

[image]

While if you add nobysame and change the above code to

```
\documentclass[twoside]{amsart}
\usepackage[alphabetic,nobysame]{amsrefs}
\begin{document}
\begin{bibdiv}
\begin{biblist}
\bib{Gan1}{article}
{author={Gan}}

\bib{Gan2}{article}
{author={Gan}}
\end{biblist}
\end{bibdiv}
\end{document}
```

and recompile, you will get the following

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Could you please elaborate a bit your answer in order to explain why the option `nobysame` does actually answer the question? Providing a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/13304) would be best.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino I added one example, hopefully it will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the bibliography style.
Changing the bibliography style from `\bibliographystyle{amsplain}` to 
`\bibliographystyle{unsrt}` worked for me.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! We prefer full examples instead of comment-like `answers` ;-)