# Printing recurrent author names instead of a dash

Tags: bibtex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change definition of \sameauthors to turn off by same dash](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51196/change-definition-of-sameauthors-to-turn-off-by-same-dash)

I am using the `amsart` class and `bibtex` with the `amsplain` style. I have a bibliography file which is called whenever I use the `bibtex` command. (I run LaTeX through Winedt). In my references, if an author occurs more than once, the name is replaced with a straight line on all subsequent repeats. The journal I am submitting to wants the author name for every reference. Does anybody know how I suppress the dash feature, so it prints the full name of the author for every reference?

Comment: Related http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51196/change-definition-of-sameauthors-to-turn-off-by-same-dash and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29381/is-it-normal-for-bibtex-to-replace-similar-author-names-with

Comment: Alan Munn's [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51200/3954) to http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/51196/3954 gives the solution.

Comment: Just put the author's name between { } and everything goes well.

Answer (score 5):

The `amsplain` bibliography style, as the name suggests, is very similar to the `plain` BibTeX style and suitable to AMS publications. We just need to use `plain` instead of `amsplain`. `:)`

```
\begin{filecontents*}{mybibfile.bib}
@book{Knuth:2005:ACP:1036677,
 author = {Knuth, Donald E.},
 title = {The Art of Computer Programming, Volume 4,  Fascicle 3: Generating All Combinations and Partitions},
 year = {2005},
 isbn = {0201853949},
 publisher = {Addison-Wesley Professional},
} 

@book{Knuth:1998:ACP:280635,
 author = {Knuth, Donald E.},
 title = {The art of computer programming,  volume 3: (2nd ed.) sorting and searching},
 year = {1998},
 isbn = {0-201-89685-0},
 publisher = {Addison Wesley Longman Publishing Co., Inc.},
 address = {Redwood City, CA, USA},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{#1.}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{mybibfile}

\end{document}
```

With `amsplain`:

[image: amsplain]

And with `plain`:

[image: plain]

I had to do this dirty trick:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{#1.}
\makeatother
```

otherwise, our output would have `[1]` instead of `1.`:

[image: plain 2]

Hope it helps. `:)`