# Consecutive references in BibTeX

Tags: bibtex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it normal for BibTeX to replace similar author names with “------”?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29381/is-it-normal-for-bibtex-to-replace-similar-author-names-with)

I have three consecutive BibTeX references where the authors list is same in all three.
When I compile BibtTeX only keeps the authors list in the first reference. In the consecutive  references, the authors list is ------ ( a long dash).

Is there a way to stop this automatic behavior?

Comment: This is dependent on the BibTeX style (`.bst`) file you use. What do you have as the `\bibliographystyle`?

Comment: \bibliographystyle{IEEEtran} 
\bibliography{IEEEabrv,IEEEfull, myfile}