# multiple author listing bibtex results in _ _ in place of authors names

Tags: bibtex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it normal for BibTeX to replace similar author names with “------”?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29381/is-it-normal-for-bibtex-to-replace-similar-author-names-with)

I had to cite two papers of same group of authors in Latex:

```
@inproceedings{Lai_etal_ICRA11_RGBD_dataset,
    author    = {Kevin Lai and
              Liefeng Bo and
              Xiaofeng Ren and
              Dieter Fox},
  title     = {A large-scale hierarchical multi-view RGB-D object dataset},
  booktitle = {ICRA},
  year      = {2011},
  pages     = {1817-1824},
  ee        = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/ICRA.2011.5980382},
  crossref  = {DBLP:conf/icra/2011},
  bibsource = {DBLP, http://dblp.uni-trier.de}
  }



@inproceedings{lai_etal_icra12,
   title = {Detection-based Object Labeling in 3D Scenes},
   author    = {Kevin Lai and 
               Liefeng Bo and
              Xiaofeng Ren and
              Dieter Fox},
   booktitle = {ICRA},
   year = {2012},
  pdf =  {http://www.cs.washington.edu/homes/kevinlai/publications/lai_icra12.pdf}
 }
```

It appears as:

[4] K. Lai, L. Bo, X. Ren, and D. Fox, “A large-scale hierarchical multi-view
rgb-d object dataset,” in ICRA, 2011, pp. 1817–1824.

[5] ——, “Detection-based object labeling in 3d scenes,” in ICRA, 2012.

I am not getting author names for the second paper.
I am using IEEEtran.bst for bibtex.

What should I do to get the proper author names?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) This question is very similar to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29381/is-it-normal-for-bibtex-to-replace-similar-author-names-with. Please take a look at it as the information there might help you. If so, that's great, and we'll probably close this question as a duplicate just to keep the place tidy and to help people find answers quickly. If not, please edit your question here to explain why so that people can better focus their attention to help you.

Comment: With no feedback, I've closed as a dupe. Comment if you want it reopening, and I'll take another look.