# biblatex ieee style same authors

Tags: biblatex

I just realized that when using `ieee` style in `biblatex`, when two articles in my bibliography share the same authors, the second article the authors disappear and a line is used instead. Is there any easy way to change this behavior without changing the style?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Update

In version v1.2 (2016/12/30) of `biblatex-ieee`, Joseph Wright added full support for the `dashed` option (https://github.com/josephwright/biblatex-ieee/issues/30). It is now enough to add

```
dashed=false
```

to the `biblatex` options.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=ieee, dashed=false]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The old version of this answer is retained for historic interest and for those who don't have access to a newer version of `biblatex-ieee` or users of a similar style that does not have an option to turn off the `dashed` behaviour.

---

### Old answer

*Normally* – that is in the standard styles, this is as easy as adding `dashed=false` to the load options of `biblatex`. The `biblatex` styles `ieee` and `ieee-alphabetic`, however, do not recognize this option, since – as @Joseph Wright pointed out – it is IEEE style to use the dash.

So you can either manually alter the author macro or disable an internal test needed for the dashed function.

To change the author macro to avoid dashes, just add the following code snippet to your preamble.

```
\renewbibmacro*{author}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseauthor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{author}}
  }
    {%
      \printnames{author}%
      \iffieldundef{authortype}
        {}
        {%
          \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
          \usebibmacro{authorstrg}%
        }%
    }
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash}%
}
```

Alternatively, you can modify the macro that saves the hash needed for author comparison to do nothing.

```
\renewbibmacro*{bbx:savehash}{}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass[ngerman, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=ieee-alphabetic, backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\renewbibmacro*{bbx:savehash}{}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{UthorA,
  author  = {Arnold Uthor},
  title   = {The Twice Intensely Tiring Lines of Erudition},
  year    = {1983},
}
@article{UthorB,
  author        = {Arnold Uthor},
  title         = {A Very Interesting Article},
  journaltitle  = {Journal of Articles},
  year          = {2000},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
  \nocite{*}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Note that the reason the styles don't currently recognise this option is that the IEEE style is to use dashes.

Comment: I've recently updated the style to add `dashed` as an option, to allow people to run it off if they need to

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the following lines to your Bibtex file:

```
@IEEEtranBSTCTL{IEEEexample:BSTcontrol,
  CTLdash_repeated_names = "no"
}
```

And the following line to your Tex file, just after `\begin{document}`:

```
\begin{document}
\bstctlcite{IEEEexample:BSTcontrol}
```

Comment: It works as per requirement without printing dash for the same name clashing. This is the only way to solve the issue. I have tried many other suggestions but does not work.

Answer (score 0):

This is answered here: [Is it normal for BibTeX to replace similar author names with "------"?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29381/is-it-normal-for-bibtex-to-replace-similar-author-names-with/347065#347065)

If you are writing a paper which asks for `IEEEtrans` (especially if this is to be published with IEEE), I would seriously consider simply using the default behavior as the result for your paper.  This is not a "fluke" that needs to be programed around, this is **exactly** how the style is programed and designed to perform.

You should always write your paper and choose your citation style based upon the style guide which has authority over your writing (teacher's choice, university style guide, corporate style guide, Chicago, APA, MLA, AP, &c.) and not your personal preferences.