# Replace "idem" with Authors' name while printing whole bibliography with Biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I need to print all the bibliography in a thesis, and I am using `\printbibliography[]` in Biblatex to do so. However, while printing the bibliography, biblatex replaces the name of recurrent authors with *idem*. However, the thesis format discourages us to use *idems*, and instead use the Author Name as a complete reference.

Following are the code segments I am using right now.

```
\usepackage[
    style=geschichtsfrkl,   
    backend=biber,
    sorting=nyt]{biblatex}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{citeinit=false, mitjahr=false}
\addbibresource{bibtex_files/CompleteBibTex_corr.bib}
\addbibresource{bibtex_files/Bib-Footnotes_corr3.bib}
```

And to print the bibliography, I am using `\citereset` as following:

```
\begin{refsection}
\citereset
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[heading=none,
notkeyword=droit-suisse,
notkeyword=droit-EU,
notkeyword=droit-americain,
notkeyword=international-law,
notkeyword=french-law,
notkeyword=droit-EU-jur,
type=book]
\end{refsection}
```

Following is a snapshot of the problem:
[image]

I am not sure where I am going wrong as the *idems* are not replaced. Any help would be great. Thanks in advance!

Please find attached below a MWE:

```
\documentclass[
    french,
    10 pt,                  % fontsize 
    openright
]{report}              % these-droit class
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[style=geschichtsfrkl,backend=biber,sorting=nyt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{baeriswyl_wirksamkeit_2008,
    Author = {Baeriswyl, Bruno},
    Journal = {Digma - Zeitschrift f{\"u}r Datenrecht und Informationssicherheit},
    Language = {German},
    Note = {OCLC: 716915160},
    Pages = {66--69},
    Shorttitle = {Die {Wirksamkeit} der {Datenschutzbeh{\"o}rden}},
    Title = {Die {Wirksamkeit} der {Datenschutzbeh{\"o}rden}: {Effizienz} und {Effektivit{\"a}t} der {Datenschutzbeh{\"o}rden} sind {Schl{\"u}sselfaktoren} eines wirkungsvollen {Datenschutzes}},
    Volume = {82008},
    Year = {2008}}

@article{baeriswyl_anonymisierung_2008,
    Author = {Baeriswyl, Bruno},
    Journal = {Digma - Zeitschrift f{\"u}r Datenrecht und Informationssicherheit},
    Language = {German},
    Note = {OCLC: 716890817},
    Pages = {14--17},
    Shorttitle = {Anonymisierung von genetischen {Daten}?},
    Title = {Anonymisierung von genetischen {Daten}?: (datenschutz)rechtliche {Aspekte} der {Anonymisierung} bei {Biobanken}},
    Volume = {82008},
    Year = {2008}}

@article{baeriswyl_wirksamkeit_2008,
    Author = {Baeriswyl, Bruno},
    Journal = {Digma - Zeitschrift f{\"u}r Datenrecht und Informationssicherheit},
    Language = {German},
    Note = {OCLC: 716915160},
    Pages = {66--69},
    Shorttitle = {Die {Wirksamkeit} der {Datenschutzbeh{\"o}rden}},
    Title = {Die {Wirksamkeit} der {Datenschutzbeh{\"o}rden}: {Effizienz} und {Effektivit{\"a}t} der {Datenschutzbeh{\"o}rden} sind {Schl{\"u}sselfaktoren} eines wirkungsvollen {Datenschutzes}},
    Volume = {82008},
    Year = {2008}}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{}
\begin{refsection}
\citereset
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[heading=Bibliographie, title=Bibliographie, type=article]
\end{refsection}

\end{document}
```

And here is the class file these_Eva.cls :

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}

% This is an adaptatin of the BFH template by bernl1
% Author: dhs1 

\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{memoir}}

\ProcessOptions

\LoadClass{memoir}


% Load Standard Packages:
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                                            %codage de sortie adapté au français
%\usepackage[standard-baselineskips]{cmbright}
\usepackage{babel}                                              % language
%\usepackage{inputenc}
%\usepackage{csquotes}                                                  % for use of biblatex
\usepackage{textcomp}                                                   % additional symbols
\usepackage{enumitem}                                                   % for intertext in lists
%\usepackage{fancyhdr}                                                  % simple manipulation of header and footer 
\usepackage{etoolbox}                                                   % color manipulation of header and footer
\usepackage{graphicx}                                                   % integration of images
\usepackage{float}                                                      % floating objects
\usepackage{subcaption}
%\usepackage{caption}                                                   % for captions of figures and tables --> not needed with memoir class
\usepackage{booktabs}                                                   % package for nicer tables
\usepackage{tocvsec2}                                                   % provides means of controlling the sectional numbering
%\usepackage{titlesec}                                      % 
\usepackage{shorttoc}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
%[Himanshu] added [hyphens] in the above line.

%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Set up page dimension
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
\setstocksize{225mm}{155mm}
\settrimmedsize{\stockheight}{\stockwidth}{*}
\setlrmarginsandblock{40mm}{20mm}{*}                %\setlrmarginsandblock{⟨spine⟩}{⟨edge⟩}{⟨ratio⟩}
\setulmarginsandblock{23mm}{25mm}{*}            % --> because headers and footers are included   \setulmarginsandblock{⟨upper⟩}{⟨lower⟩}{⟨ratio⟩}
%%% Alternatively: %%%
%\settypeblocksize{*}{115mm}{1.512}         % \settypeblocksize{⟨height⟩}{⟨width⟩}{⟨ratio⟩}
%\setlrmargins{20mm}{*}{*}
%\setulmargins{30mm}{*}{*}

%----------%% is defined accordingly to word-Vorlage from Schultess: -----------------
\setheaderspaces{12.25mm}{*}{1}                 % \setheaderspaces{⟨headdrop⟩}{⟨headsep⟩}{⟨ratio⟩} (above and below the header)
\setheadfoot{13pt}{12.5mm}
\setmarginnotes{6mm}{8mm}{10pt} 
\sideparmargin{outer}   

%\setfootins{⟨length for normal⟩}{⟨length for minipage⟩}
%When footnotes are added to the text block they are added \skip\footins below the text. Since this is a skip it usually needs special syntax to change it. Instead we have provided an interface to set it. 5 The default sizes are \bigskipamount.

%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Fonts and text size, headers and footers content
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


\footmarkstyle{#1.\hfill}
\setlength{\footmarkwidth}{1.8em}
\setlength{\footmarksep}{0em}

\rmfamily %Roman family

\pagestyle{ruled}
\aliaspagestyle{chapter}{ruled}             % header and footers d'une page chapitre sont comme dans le pagestyle défini. (Sans ça on aurait le style "plain")


%-------------------------- Headings -----------------------
% part:
% chapter:

      \makechapterstyle{lae}{ 
      \clearpage
       \renewcommand{\chapnamefont}{\sffamily\Huge\bfseries}
     \renewcommand{\chapnumfont}{\sffamily\Huge\bfseries}       % per default same value as chapnamefront
     \renewcommand{\chaptitlefont}{\sffamily\Huge\bfseries}
      \renewcommand{\chapterheadstart}{}
     \renewcommand{\afterchapternum}{:\chapternamenum}        % \midchapskip space between number and title
     \setlength{\beforechapskip}{6.4mm}
    \setlength{\afterchapskip}{2.1mm}       % 2.1mm = 6pt
    }
    \headstyles{bringhurst}
     \chapterstyle{lae}

 % section:

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}
    \setlength{\beforesecskip}{4.2mm}   
    \setlength{\aftersecskip}{2.1mm}
      %\setSindent{⟨length⟩}        
   \setsecheadstyle{\LARGE\bfseries\raggedright}%

 % sub-section:

  \renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}.}
    \setlength{\beforesubsecskip}{3.8mm}    
    \setlength{\aftersubsecskip}{2.1mm}     
   \setsubsecheadstyle{\Large\bfseries\raggedright}%

% sub-sub section: 

  \renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}.}
    \setlength{\beforesubsubsecskip}{11pt}  
    \setlength{\aftersubsubsecskip}{2.1mm}      
   \setsubsubsecheadstyle{\large\mdseries\slshape\raggedright}%

% paragraph

  \renewcommand{\theparagraph}{(\alph{paragraph})}
    \setlength{\beforeparaskip}{3.9mm}  
    \setlength{\afterparaskip}{2.1 mm}
     \setparaindent{0pt}        
   \setparaheadstyle{\normalsize\bfseries\slshape\raggedright}%

 % sub-paragraph
    \setlength{\beforesubparaskip}{4.2mm}   
    \setlength{\aftersubparaskip}{2.1 mm}       
   \setsubparaheadstyle{\normalsize\bfseries\raggedright}%

% lists:

%-------------------------- Paragraphs -----------------------
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}             % no indent for new paragraphs
\setlength{\parskip}{3.2mm}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%




% Package to facilitate placement of boxes at absolute positions
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1mm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{1mm}
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------

% Hyperref Package (Create links in a pdf)
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[
    pdftex,ngerman,bookmarks,plainpages=false,pdfpagelabels,
    backref = {false},                                                  % No index backreference
    colorlinks = {true},                                                % Color links in a PDF
    hypertexnames = {true},                                             % no failures "same page(i)"
    bookmarksopen = {true},                                             % opens the bar on the left side
    bookmarksopenlevel = {0},                                           % depth of opened bookmarksa
    linkcolor = {black},                                            % Color of Links
    citecolor = {black},                                            % Color of Cite-Links
    urlcolor = {black},                                             % Color of URLs
]{hyperref}

\urlstyle{sf}


\endinput
```

Comment: Please consider turning the code snippets into a full example document that other people can copy, paste and compile without further ado. This is what we call an MWE (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/MWEB (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864).

Comment: Please note that this is almost an MWE, but not quite: We don't have `class/these_Eva`. And `\thesis.bib` is quite probably going to be dangerous or wrong, better use `\jobname.bib`. `heading=Bibliographie` also looks wrong if you have not defined a special bibheading called `Bibliographie`.

Comment: Done! Added the class file and made the changes.

Comment: For future questions: The preferred way to avoid the issue of us not having a highly customised class is by trying to reproduce the example with one of the standard classes (`article`, `report`, `book`) and using that if possible. In this case it is easily possible to use `article` and avoid the `class/these_Eva` malarkey.

Comment: Changed it, sorry for the inconvenience. Will keep in mind for the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike the standard styles `geschichtsfrkl` has no option to turn off the "idem"/"dashed" behaviour (cf. [Get full name twice in Bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49140/35864), some contributed styles also have this option even if they implement styles that are strict about using dashes: [biblatex ieee style same authors](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/131625/35864)). `geschichtsfrkl` also does not use a common macro for the tests. That means we have to modify the bibmacros that print the names directly.

`\citereset` does not help here because it would have to apply to all entries separately and, more importantly, because it does not actually reset the bibliography idem tracker, so it is not needed.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=geschichtsfrkl, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{author}{%
  \ifnameundef{author}{}%
      {\printnames{author}\isdot}}
\renewbibmacro*{author/editor}{%
   \ifboolexpr{test{\ifnameundef{author}} or bool{cbx:frg}}{%
      \ifnameundef{editor}{%
          \BibliographyWarning{Fehlender Autor *und* Herausgeber!}%
      }{%
        \printnames[author]{editor}\isdot% (Hrsg.)
        \addspace\printtext[parens]{\bibstring{editor}}}%
   }{\usebibmacro{author}}%
}%
\makeatother

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b,knuth:ct:c}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Knuth, Donald E.: Computers & Typesetting, vol. A: The T E Xbook, Reading, Mass. 1984.//Knuth, Donald E.: Computers & Typesetting, vol. B: T E X: The Program, Reading, Mass. 1986.//Knuth, Donald E.: Computers & Typesetting, vol. C: The METAFONTbook, Reading, Mass. 1986.]

Comment: Thanks @moewe, this did work. I was not sure that the problem was with `geschichtsfrkl` style.

Comment: @HimanshuVerma Well, it's not really a *problem* of the style. It's just a feature of the style you can't turn off easily with one simple option (like the similar `dashed` feature of the standard styles). Since I understand `geschichtsfrkl` is supposed to implement the requirements of a particular university that is not entirely unreasonable. (Though you can always ask the style author to implement a feature to turn this off more easily.)