# Problems with rendering references sections correctly

Tags: biblatex

I have a generated a minimal reproducible example and I just can't get it to work as I want.

When I run this example it will basically replace the name of the authors in the reference list with a straight line.
Is this by design?
If I just add any letter to any of the author names it gets displayed as I want it.
The first reference is a generic book reference while the second is a page reference.

This is the contents of the tex-file

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
 
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\usepackage[style=ieee]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
 
\begin{document}

\title{Projektrapport}
\author{
  Name 1, Name 2, Name 3
}
\date{2020-XX-YY}

\maketitle

\section*{Introduktion}
Hello \cite{stokastik}
World \cite{stok1}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

This is the contents of the references.bib file

```
@book{stokastik,
    author      = "Sven Erick Alm and Tom Britton",
    maintitle   = "Stokastik Sannolikhetsteori och statistikteori med tillämpningar",
    volume      = "1",
    title       = "Stokastik",
    publisher   = "Liber",
    year        = "2018",
    ISBN        = "978-91-47-05351-3",
}

@inbook{stok1,
    author      = "Sven Erick Alm and Tom Britton",
    title       = {Stokastik Sannolikhetsteori och statistikteori med tillämpningar},
    volume      = "1",
    publisher   = "Liber",
    year        = "2018",
    pages       = {72-89,69, 112,22},
    edition     = "second",
    ISBN        = "978-91-47-05351-3",
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If I remember correctly, this is the expected behaviour if you use the `ieee` style.

Comment: Since your question is quite similar/identical to [biblatex ieee style same authors](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/131625/134144), I vote to close yours as a duplicate to the before mentioned question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `dashed=false` false to the options of `biblatex` (as in `\usepackage[style=ieee, dashed=false]{biblatex}`) results in the following output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it works as expected now :-)