# Author multiple times in Biblatex

Tags: biblatex, ieee-style

I am using the IEEE style in my bibliography with `biblatex`. Unfortunately, I use the same authors with "et al." several times. In some cases, LaTeX then replaces the author field in the pdf with a horizontal line (in the article reference type), but not for every authors I use multiple times. Does someone have ideas what I can do?

Comment: See if https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/131625/35864 helps. If you need more specific help, you'll have to show us a short example document citing a few problematic `.bib` entries (of course we'd also have to see the `.bib` entries themselves) in the form of an MWE (see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864 and https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864).

Comment: @moewe thank you very much! Putting "dashed=false" into the preamble where I load the package worked! Thanks!!!