# biblatex not displaying author (only sometimes)

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, cross-referencing, author

My bibliography is not showing the author of some of my references. Which ones it shows seems to be affected by the order in which i cite them, and I have no idea whats going on.
The actual document has 20+ references and seems to be completely random which ones work and which don't. I am using overleaf if that matters.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel} %referencing package
\usepackage{csquotes} %references/quotes

\usepackage[style=ieee]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sample.bib}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}

\chapter{Introduction}
%\cite{MATLAB:docs:max} 
\cite{MATLAB:2020}

\section{Next Section}
\cite{MATLAB:docs:find} \cite{MATLAB:docs:max} \cite{MATLAB:docs:for}

\printbibliography[title={References}, heading=bibintoc]

\end{document}
```

results in:
[image]

and if i uncomment the first "\cite{MATLAB:docs:max}"

```
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}

\chapter{Introduction}
\cite{MATLAB:docs:max} 
\cite{MATLAB:2020}

\section{Next Section}
\cite{MATLAB:docs:find} \cite{MATLAB:docs:max} \cite{MATLAB:docs:for}

\printbibliography[title={References}, heading=bibintoc]

\end{document}
```

it changes which authors it does/doesnt show correctly:
[image]

Full code for references "sample.bib"

```
@book{MATLAB:2020,
year = {2020},
author = {MATLAB},
title = {9.8.0.1417392 (R2020a)},
publisher = {The MathWorks Inc.},
address = {Natick, Massachusetts}
}


@online{MATLAB:docs:find,
    author = "Mathworks ",
    title = "Find",
    year = "2021",
    url  = "https://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html",
    addendum = "(accessed: \today)",
    keywords = "MATLAB,documentation, Mathworks, function"
}

@online{MATLAB:docs:max,
    author = "Mathworks ",
    title = "Max",
    year = "2021",
    url  = "https://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html",
    addendum = "(accessed: \today)",
    keywords = "MATLAB,documentation, Mathworks, function"
}

@online{MATLAB:docs:for,
    author = "Mathworks",
    title = "For",
    year = "2021",
    url  = "https://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/for.html",
    addendum = "(accessed: \today)",
    keywords = "MATLAB,documentation, Mathworks, function"
}
```

Comment: Isn't that just the standard marker for a repeated author? This is used by some styles/journals.

Comment: In addition, references are numbered in their order of appearance. But you can change this behaviour setting another style.

Comment: BTW, `babel` is not a “referencing package” ;)

Comment: Yes, by default `biblatex-ieee` dashes same authors. You can turn that off with an option, though https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/131625/35864. Since `ieee` is a numeric style, I don't think it makes much sense to keep have `dashed=true,` be the default, so I opened https://github.com/josephwright/biblatex-ieee/issues/60 & https://github.com/josephwright/biblatex-ieee/pull/61