# Bibliography entry wrong

Tags: bibtex, ieee-style

I have a bibliography entry which shows up in my .bib file as

```
    @article{Weber1885,
    author = {Weber, H F},
    journal = {Sitzungsberichte der Akademie der Wissenschaften zu Berlin},
    pages = {809--815},
    title = {{Das W\"{a}rmeleitungsverm\"{o}gen der tropfbaren Fl\"{u}ssigkeiten}},
    year = {1885}
    }
```

However when I compile this the entry shows the authors name as ----- instead of H F Weber (as shown in the picture). I have no idea what to do, however, it does seem to be linked to another article in my .bib file which is:

```
  @article{Weber1880,
  author = {Weber, H F},
  journal = {Annalen der Physik und Chemie},
  number = {5},
  title = {{Untersuchungen \"{u}ber die W\"{a}rmeleitung in Fl\"{u}ssigkeiten}},
  volume = {10},
  year = {1880}
  }
```

In the .bbl file the same reference shows up as:

```
 \bibitem{Weber1885a}
   ------, ``{Das W\"{a}rmeleitungsverm\"{o}gen der tropfbaren Fl\"{u}ssigkeiten},'' \emph{Sitzungsberichte der Akademie der Wissenschaften zu Berlin}, vol.~1, pp. 809--815, 1885.
```

Hence why I see the result I see in the bibliography...
Has anyone come across this or have a solution?

Cheers
[image: Bibliography problem]

Comment: do you use a verbose-bibstyle? then maybe set `dashed=false` in your config: `\usepackage[style=verbose,dashed=false]`. If not, please provide a fully compilable MWE.

Comment: It's a common abbreviation used in bibliographies. It means 'ditto'. The author is omitted because it's the same as the immediately previous entry.

Comment: John, Is there a way around this abbreviation?
@musicman, what package is this associated with? (\usepackage[style=verbose,dashed=false])

Comment: sorry of course `\usepackage[style=verbose,dashed=false]{biblatex}` The option `dashed=false` will reprint the author information if it's repeated

Comment: I'm not using the biblatex package. I am using the cite package, without any optional arguments. Is there anything to disable what I am seeing in this package. 

My bibliography is defined as:
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{IEEEfull,BiBTeX/library}

Comment: if you're not using the `biblatex` package you shouldn't tag your question with `biblatex`...

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29381/586.