# How to remove hyphen before reference

Tags: bibtex

[image]
How can I solve this? what's the problem causing it? here's a sample of the .bib file [image] Thanks!

here's my packages and document set up, any help would be appreciated

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{geometry}
\newgeometry{left=2cm, right=2cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}

\newtheorem{defi}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{exm}{Example}[section]
\newtheorem{rem}{Remark}[section]
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}[section]
\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}[section]
\newenvironment{Proof}{\begin{sloppypar}\noindent{\sf Proof.}}{\end{sloppypar}}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\begin{document}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}    
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{References}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is because of the bibliography style you are using. This style says that if there are two references by the same author, only the first should have the name, the others are replaced by a dash. Usually it is possible to workaround this, but it's impossible to say with further information. Please post a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407) so that we can get rid of that dash for you.

Comment: The symbol is not a hyphen, it's a "3-emdash" symbol. As Phelype has pointed out in an earlier comment, its appearance is a feature of the bibliography style that's you selected.

Comment: Aside: Rather than be bothered by the 3-emdash symbol, I'd be *horrified* by the lower-casing of the names `einstein`, `yang`, and `mills`. Please, please write the field as `author = {On the integrability of the {Einstein}-{Yang}-{Mills} equations},`; this will prevent BibTeX from applying sentence style (which induces lowercasing) to the three names in question.

Comment: Thank you guys I edited my question I hope that's the correct way to provide the MWE. (a complete noob here).

Comment: @Neek see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29381/36296

Comment: Thank you @samcarter I was able to find the solution there and

Comment: @Mico for you time and suggestions.

Comment: @samcarter Should I delete this if it's duplicate of another post?

Comment: @Neek Please do not delete. Duplicates are a good thing, they increase the searchability for a given problem.