# how do I cite a springer conference using ieeetran?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, ieeetran

I want to cite a conference using ieeetran style as in the following:

```
@incollection{fuext,
    year={2004, May 2-6},
    booktitle={$23^{rd}$ International Conference on the Theory and Applications of Cryptographic Techniques (EUROCRYPT)},
    volume={3027},
    title={Fuzzy Extractors: How to Generate Strong Keys from Biometrics and Other Noisy Data},
    publisher={{LNCS}, Springer Berlin Heidelberg},
    author={Dodis, Yevgeniy and Reyzin, Leonid and Smith, Adam},
    address={Interlaken, Switzerland},
    pages={523-540},
}
```

The output is coming like:

> Y. Dodis, L. Reyzin, and A. Smith, "Fuzzy extractors: How to generate strong keys from biometrics and other noisy data," in 23rd International Conference on the Theory and Applications of Cryptographic Techniques (EUROCRYPT). Interlaken, Switzerland: LNCS, Springer Berlin Heidelberg, 2004, May 2-6, vol. 3027, pp. 523–540.

The output which I wish to have:

> Y. Dodis, L. Reyzin, and A. Smith, "Fuzzy extractors: How to generate strong keys from biometrics and other noisy data," in 23rd International Conference on the Theory and Applications of Cryptographic Techniques (EUROCRYPT), Interlaken, Switzerland, LNCS, Springer Berlin Heidelberg, 2004, May 2-6, vol. 3027, pp. 523–540.

Comment: So, just for all of us to be on the same page... You are asking how to change the punctuation *before and after the address field*? change colon to comma *before* and double colon to comma *after* the field?

Comment: @Johannes_B yes...

Comment: use `@inproceedings` instead of `@incollection`.

Comment: @nidhin vol. 3027. Switzerland: is appearing even after enclosing in inproceedings. It should be: vol. 3027,    and Switzerland,

Comment: The period and the semicolon are hard-coded in `IEEEtran.bst`. I am pretty sure IEEE wants it that way.

Comment: @rudreshdwivedi Please find my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended way to cite a conference proceeding is to use `@inproceedings` instead of `@incollection` in `ieeetrans`. In either cases, IEEE does not want you to change those styles when submitting an article to them. But your requirement seems little different.

One way to achieve the desired output is to use a customized version of [IEEEtrans.bst](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/IEEEtran/IEEEtranS.bst). Go for it only if you have lot of similar bib entries else go for the workaround given below.

You can achieve the desired output by including `publisher` entry in `address`. A MWE is given below:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{refs.bib}
@incollection{fuext1,
    year={2004, May 2-6},
    booktitle={$23^{rd}$ International Conference on the Theory and Applications of Cryptographic Techniques (EUROCRYPT)},
    volume={3027},
    title={Fuzzy Extractors: How to Generate Strong Keys from Biometrics and Other Noisy Data},
    publisher={{LNCS}, Springer Berlin Heidelberg},
    author={Dodis, Yevgeniy and Reyzin, Leonid and Smith, Adam},
    address={Interlaken, Switzerland},
    pages={523-540},
}

@incollection{fuext2,
    year={2004, May 2-6},
    booktitle={$23^{rd}$ International Conference on the Theory and Applications of Cryptographic Techniques (EUROCRYPT)},
    volume={3027},
    title={Fuzzy Extractors: How to Generate Strong Keys from Biometrics and Other Noisy Data},
    author={Dodiz, Yevgeniy and Reyzin, Leonid and Smith, Adam},
    address={Interlaken, Switzerland, {LNCS}, Springer Berlin Heidelberg},
    pages={523-540},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
Old \cite{fuext1} and New\cite{fuext2}.
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{refs}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

PS: Author name in the second entry has edited to avoid the [dash because of same author name](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29381/28557).