# Name list replaced by dash in bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, ieee-style

I am citing 2 papers from the same authors. I read that LaTeX puts a dash if the authors are the same. How do I remove that dash and still put in all the authors name like usual?

```
@article{resnet,
    author  = "Kaiming He and Xiangyu Zhang and Shaoqing Ren and Jian Sun",
    title   = "Deep Residual Learning for Image Recognition",
    year    = "2015",
    journal = "ArXiv"
}

@article{heinitialization,
    author  = "Kaiming He and Xiangyu Zhang and Shaoqing Ren and Jian Sun",
    title   = "Delving Deep into Rectifiers: Surpassing Human-Level Performance on ImageNet Classification",
    year    = "2014",
    journal = "ArXiv"
}
```

[image]

```
\clearpage
\section*{References}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{refs.bib}
```

i add the function \usepackage[style=ieee,dashed=false]{biblatex} but my references become the refs.bib

[image]

Comment: seen this yet? [Is it normal for BibTeX to replace similar author names with "------"?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29381/117534)

Comment: all my references become "refs.bib"

Comment: @Troy the function dont work for me

Comment: If you switch from bibtex to biblatex, you should also replace `\bibliography{...}` with `\printbibliography` and compile with biber instead of bibtex.

Comment: Can you add a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407) that shows us what problem you are currently facing?