# Finding right bib entry for a reference

Tags: bibliographies

I want to know which IEEEtran bib entry fits this reference?

```
J. Dechaux, E. Filiol, and J. Fizaine. (2010). Office Documents:
New Weapons of Cyberwarfare. [Online]. Available: http://archive.hack.lu/2010/Filiol-Office-Documents-New-Weapons-of-Cyberwarfare-paper.pdf
```

Any thought?

UPDATE:

I use

```
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtranS}
\bibliography{mybibfile}
```

and also I use `\cite{}` package in the text. For example, conference proceedings in `mybibfile` are shown as

```
@inproceedings{Shafiq08,
  author = {M. Z. Shafiq and S. A. Khayam and M. Farooq},
  title = {Embedded malware detection using markov n-grams},
  booktitle  = {Proceedings of the 5th International Conference on Detection of Intrusions and Malware and Vulnerability Assessment},
  year = {2008},
  pages = { 88 - 107  },
}
```

Comment: Please tell us more about this particular entry. E.g., is it available only online? And, please confirm that you employ the `IEEEtran` bibliography style. Do you use a citation management package, such as `cite`?

Comment: OK. The link was broken (in the original paper I saw) and I pasted the new one. Other information are also included in the updated post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various entry types defined in `IEEEtranS.bst` that would fit such an entry, like `booklet`, `techreport`, `unpublished`, `misc`, `electronic`. The `electronic` entry seems to produce the format in your example.

Code (`.bib` file):

```
@IEEEtranBSTCTL{IEEEexample:BSTcontrol,
  CTLdash_repeated_names = "no"
}

@booklet{dechauxbo,
    author = {Jonathan Dechaux and Eric Filiol and Jean-Paul Fizaine},
    title = {Office Documents: New Weapons of Cyberwarfare},
    url = {http://archive.hack.lu/2010/Filiol-Office-Documents-New-Weapons-of-Cyberwarfare-paper.pdf},
    organization = {ESIEA Laval, Laboratoire de cryptologie et de virologie op\'erationnelles},
    address = {38 rue des Dr Calmette et Gu\'erin, 53000 Laval, France},
    year = {2010}
}

@techreport{dechauxtr,
    author = {Jonathan Dechaux and Eric Filiol and Jean-Paul Fizaine},
    title = {Office Documents: New Weapons of Cyberwarfare},
    url = {http://archive.hack.lu/2010/Filiol-Office-Documents-New-Weapons-of-Cyberwarfare-paper.pdf},
    institution = {ESIEA Laval},
    year = {2010}
}

@unpublished{dechauxup,
    author = {Jonathan Dechaux and Eric Filiol and Jean-Paul Fizaine},
    title = {Office Documents: New Weapons of Cyberwarfare},
    url = {http://archive.hack.lu/2010/Filiol-Office-Documents-New-Weapons-of-Cyberwarfare-paper.pdf},
    year = {2010}
}

@misc{dechauxmi,
    author = {Jonathan Dechaux and Eric Filiol and Jean-Paul Fizaine},
    title = {Office Documents: New Weapons of Cyberwarfare},
    url = {http://archive.hack.lu/2010/Filiol-Office-Documents-New-Weapons-of-Cyberwarfare-paper.pdf},
    organization = {ESIEA Laval},
    year = {2010}
}

@electronic{dechauxel,
    author = {Jonathan Dechaux and Eric Filiol and Jean-Paul Fizaine},
    title = {Office Documents: New Weapons of Cyberwarfare},
    url = {http://archive.hack.lu/2010/Filiol-Office-Documents-New-Weapons-of-Cyberwarfare-paper.pdf},
    year = {2010}
}
```

Code (`.tex`):

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\begin{document}
\bstctlcite{IEEEexample:BSTcontrol}
\noindent \cite{dechauxbo} booklet\\
\cite{dechauxtr} techreport\\
\cite{dechauxup} unpublished\\
\cite{dechauxmi} misc\\
\cite{dechauxel} electronic

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtranS}
\bibliography{dechaux}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Note that I have included the full organization and address only for the `booklet` entry, most other types also support these fields. The `BSTcontrol` part is just to print the author names on repeated entries for this example (see [Is it normal for BibTeX to replace similar author names with "------"?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29381/is-it-normal-for-bibtex-to-replace-similar-author-names-with)), it is not needed in a real document (unless you want to suppress the dash of course).